# The Curious Case of Steve Ballmer

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Steve Ballmer is the ex-CEO of Microsoft, and in a [recent article](https://mspoweruser.com/steve-ballmer-still-not-know-wrong-mobile/), claimed that he "still does not know what he did wrong with mobile".

As [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/)'s newsletter pointed out, "That article's title could be ended at so many spots and still be accurate".

Given no input, output the following:

```
Steve Ballmer still does not know.
Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did.
Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong.
Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile.
```

This must be outputted exactly as shown, and must be the only output of your program. You may include a single trailing newline.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins

Comment: When I saw the title / tags I thought that the output would be `developers developers ...`

Comment: **tcl, 25** — `while 1 {puts developers}` — [demo](http://rextester.com/BZDE18827)

Comment: **braingolf, 23** - `1"developers "[!@11 1>]` :P

Comment: And I thought of xkcd's [Ballmer Peak](https://xkcd.com/323)

Comment: Can we output a multiline string containing that? i.e. the actual output of our program is `"Steve Ballmer still does not know.\n...Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile.\n"`

Comment: I don't suppose you'd allow a leading space on each line?

Comment: @Riker sure you can

Comment: @Shaggy nope, no trailing whitespace

Comment: But what about *leading*, Mayube?! ;)

Comment: @Shaggy I was already going to say no, but now you get a triple no for that godaweful pun.

Comment: @Mayube Is there an optional trailing new-line, or is it required?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 optional

Comment: I'm surprised there's no MS powershell attempt.

Comment: **yes, 14** — `yes developers`

Comment: **pyth, 13** -- `#"developers `

Comment: actually you need p to print sans trailing newlines `#p"developers` so 14 bytes

Comment: @tfbninja it wasn't a codeproject article, just a general tech news article they sent out in their daily newsletter a few months back. They always add a witty little subtitle beneath the titles of all the articles in the newsletter, that's the source of the challenge

Answer (score 28):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>100</s> <s>99</s> <s>99</s> 97 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to ovs</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to Dennis</sup>

```python
for i in b'!-3?':print('Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile'[:i]+'.')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoJADAXQq3xWlRjdsGND4hVcGheQqU5DacnQMPH043v7L7Lb0NrHCwRiWKi7DRONexGLCz2DT8ZjVt244AhRRXI@YB5YzStqngOZkSShFrcvqkTG5oso02uU95Xu1Lf2Bw)

Answer (score 19):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

4 bytes saved with inspiration from [Kevin's Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123976/47066)

```
„€Ž†©'–Ñ…€À€½ƒ§“mer„â‚à€–ƒ€“”™¸ïß”[Žì'.«=¨ð«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcO8R01rju591LDg0Er1Rw2TD0981LAMKHS4AUgc2nts0qHljxrm5KYWAVUeXvSoYdbhBUAJoMJjk8D0nEcNcx@1LDq04/D6w/OB7Oijew@vUdc7tNr20IrDGw6t/v8fAA)

**Explanation**

```
„€Ž†©                                         # push "with mobile"
     '–Ñ                                      # push "wrong"
        …€À€½ƒ§                               # push "what he did"
               “mer„â‚à€–ƒ€“                  # push "mer still does not know"
                            ”™¸ïß”            # push "Steve Ball"
                                  [Ž          # loop until stack is empty
                                    ì         # prepend the top string to the 2nd top string
                                     '.«      # append a dot
                                        =     # print without popping
                                         ¨    # remove the dot
                                          ð«  # append a space
```

Comment: Oh nice, managed to use dictionary compression for everything but `Ballmer`?

Comment: @Mayube: Yeah. I got it partially now (ball) to save a byte by restructuring the original string :)

Comment: looks much better now, if only you could compress that `mer`

Comment: @Mayube: I could hide it by compressing `me` but unfortunately that wouldn't save any bytes :/

Comment: This is 97 bytes by my count.

Comment: @StigHemmer: It is 44 bytes in the [05AB1E code page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

Comment: what about compressing mermaid and then subtracting maid?

Answer (score 17):

### Haskell, 96 bytes

```
(++".\n")=<<scanl(++)"Steve Ballmer still does not know"[" what he did"," wrong"," with mobile"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBDsIgEEbhq/yZlU2NJygbr9ClukCZAOkwGBjt8bFx976XfN9YZIzoTvNMl7vS5Jalv7zKMSZajb@Mqxcp3NAtiyBU7tBq2LTudCPsyRsSI@RA54OtavxHtoRSn1mYHqP4rHB4f2y1hjh@)

`scanl` is like `foldl` (or reduce as it is called in other languages) except it returns a list of all intermediate results instead of just the final one. Each intermediate result is appended with `".\n"` and all of them are concatenated into a single string.

Answer (score 16):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>82</s> 75 bytes

*Thanks to Neil for saving 7 bytes.*

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile.
 w
.¶$`$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBDYAgDAXQO1P8g/HIEK7gAmJopLHQBBq7mQO4GL7XybilOcNu9BC2JFKpYxiLICsNNDXcTR1ekqEQMmd413bB2QqqniwUAzzE712OZZ3zBw)

#### Explanation

```
Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile.
```

Initialise the working string to the full headline.

```
 w
.¶$`$&
```

As pointed out by Neil, all three truncations are made before a word starting with `w`, and there are no other words starting with `w`. So we match a space followed by a `w` to find the truncation points. At these points, we insert the following:

- `.¶`, a period and a linefeed to truncate the sentence and begin a new one.
- `` $` ``, the entire string in front of the match, so that the next sentence starts over from the beginning.
- `$&`, the space and `w` again, so that they're also part of the next sentence.

We don't need to match the `mobile` explicitly, because that will simply be what's left over on the third match.

Comment: You only need to match on <space>w and replace with ``.¶$`$&``.

Comment: @Neil Oh, that's really neat, thank you. :)

Answer (score 9):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 88 bytes

*8 bytes saved by @MartinEnder!*

```
/1/Steve Ballmer still does not know//2/1 what he did//3/2 wrong/1.
2.
3.
3 with mobile.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcLRDcMgDAXA/0zxJuAJskFX6ARUWAXVwVJslfFpT@davYvvzcxnyFfwqKqX3PAYqmgmjmmBz7RFFmasXgNd0EYjTxas2@abOR0lHec/1oiOy15DJe39Aw)

Comment: You can save a bit more by moving the previous prefix into each substitution: https://tio.run/##BcHBDcMgEATAP1VsBawAV5AWUgEWp4B8BsmHTPlkxjRbFdubgd8pr@CTVW95YLOpogwx9DFx9bHIyIBV80QVlFbIxIj1jP4jDyasNivucTYVBu@id8m7w@/9Bw

Comment: @MartinEnder That's particularly clever. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and another 5 by dropping `4` altogether: https://tio.run/##DcLRDcMgDAXA/0zxJuAJskFX6ARUWAXVwVJslfFpT@davYvvzcxnyFfwqKqX3PAYqmgmjmmBz7RFFmasXgNd0EYjTxas2@abOR0lHec/1oiOy15DJe39Aw

Comment: @MartinEnder "Yes, I'll have a nr. 3 with mobile, please."

Answer (score 9):

## PHP, <strike>104</strike> <strike>95</strike> 94 bytes

```
<?=$a="Steve Ballmer still does not know",$a=".
$a what he did",$a.=" wrong",$a?> with mobile.
```

Comment: Missing "what"?

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, <s>127</s> 126 bytes

```
()->{String t="Steve Ballmer still does not know",d=".\n";return t+d+(t+=" what he did")+d+(t+=" wrong")+d+t+" with mobile.";}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@KonstantinCh*.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##RY8xbsMwDEX3nOJDkww3uoDhDt2bJWObQbHYWIlMGRLtIAh8dldtDRQgh0/@4b2rne0@jsRXd1u7YHPGu/X83AGehdKX7QiHnwgcJXm@oNNVU/JStkwWK77DAYwWq672r8@tJ606Cs2ENxvCQKlUfQhwkTI4Cm4c7@rFtcp8smoSyZQYUrtaS90q3Hsr6AnOO1X9X1Pky2@WuiQvPYZ49oGMapa12RWicTqHQrSBzdE7DEVJ/2F9nGCrzeeRhQYTJzFjeUlgzabYbXrL@g0)

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I stole your idea, it's much better than my looping approach.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder No problem at all, since I see you've credited me. :) Btw, `string` can't be `var` in your C# lambda?

Comment: No because I'm declaring multiple at once.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ah of course, my bad.. And `()=>{var t="Steve Ballmer still does not know";return t+".\n"+(t+=" what he did")+".\n"+(t+=" wrong")+".\n"+t+" with mobile"+".";};` is unfortunately three bytes longer.

Comment: True but see my new version, you can probably make use of it too to save some bytes.

Comment: Can you use verbatim strings like @Shaggy's answer to save bytes?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Nope, verbatism-Strings aren't not possible in Java without `String.format`. As for your previous comment, I could do (124 bytes): `()->m.c(33)+m.c(45)+m.c(51)+m.c(63)n->"Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile".substring(0,n)+".\n"` (where `m` is the anonymous function's interface), but if I'm not mistaken I've read in Meta that you aren't allowed to have > 1 anonymous function. So it would be `()->c(33)+c(45)+c(51)+c(63)String c(int n){"Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile".substring(0,n)+".\n";}` instead, which is 131 bytes.

Comment: Have you got a link to that meta post? I've used multiple anonymous methods in answers a few times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59683/discussion-between-kevin-cruijssen-and-thelethalcoder).

Comment: [Konstantin Ch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70202/konstantin-ch) suggests changing the `"+d` at the end to `."` to save a byte as the final linefeed is optional.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 46 bytes

```
”™¸ïßme”“r„â‚à€–ƒ€“«…€À€½ƒ§'–Ñ„€Ž†©).pvyðý'.«»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPcRy2LDu04vP7w/NxUEK9hTtGjhnmHFz1qmHV4waOmNY8aJh@bBKbnHFr9qGEZkHm4AUgc2nts0qHl6kDpwxOBGoAiR/c@alhwaKWmXkFZ5eENh/eq6x1afWj3//8A)

Comment: This is 98 bytes by my count.

Comment: @StigHemmer 05AB1E uses [its own code-page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md) with 256 bytes, which encodes each character to a single byte. Hence the 46 bytes, even though it's a lot more bytes in basic UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 112 bytes

```c
f(){printf("%.33s.\n%1$.45s.\n%1$s.\n%1$s with mobile.","Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc2xDsIgGEXhV7khNoFESUx16uYruLog0EKEnwaIDE2fHR10Ot929GnRuveZi23NnurM2SDHscgHDeeDvFx/@gfNV4eYnj5YyY7sXu3b4qZCiDajVB8CTLIFlCpelBqaUxXOwniDlhMtTEx7j8oTF9jwPU/Y@wc)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>52</s> 46 bytes

```
“ṬċḌ)⁹œḃṣ⁷Ṅḋ%W3Œƭ;ḷẓ“£Ṿ⁴'Þḣ~ẉ“¥Ị)“Ṡ8gÐ/»;\p”.Y
```

Credits for `ṬċḌ)⁹œḃṣ⁷Ṅḋ%W3Œƭ;ḷẓ` go to @EriktheOutgolfer, who used it in [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124000/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO9cc6X64o0fzUePOo5Mf7mh@uHPxo8btD3e2PNzRrRpufHTSsbXWD3dsf7hrMlD1ocUPd@571LhF/fC8hzsW1z3c1QkSXPpwd5cm2KwFFumHJ@gf2m0dU/CoYa5e5P//AA)

#### How it works

The lion share of the work is done by Jelly's dictionary compression here.

```
ṬċḌ)⁹œḃṣ⁷Ṅḋ%W3Œƭ;ḷẓ
```

encodes

```
Steve| Ball|mer| still| do|es| no|t| know
```

there `|` indicates boundaries between words that where fetched from the dictionary and strings that were encoded character by character (`mer`, `es`, and `t`).

Similarly, `£Ṿ⁴'Þḣ~ẉ` encodes  `what| he| did` (surprisingly, `he` does *not* come from the dictionary), `¥Ị)` encodes  `wrong`, and `Ṡ8gÐ/` encodes  `with| mobile`.

```
“ṬċḌ)⁹œḃṣ⁷Ṅḋ%W3Œƭ;ḷẓ“£Ṿ⁴'Þḣ~ẉ“¥Ị)“Ṡ8gÐ/»
```

thus yields the string array

```
“Steve Ballmer still does not know“ what he did“ wrong“ with mobile”
```

`;\` cumulatively reduces by concatenation, building the phrases on each line.

Finally, `p”.` computes the Cartesian product of these phrases and the dot character, and `Y` separates the resulting sentences by linefeeds.

Comment: By my count this is 97 bytes.

Comment: @StigHemmer In UTF-8, it would be. However, Jelly also supports [this single-byte character set](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 102 bytes

```
_=>(s="Steve Ballmer still does not know")+`.
${s+=" what he did"}.
${s+=" wrong"}.
${s} with mobile.`
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(
_=>(s="Steve Ballmer still does not know")+`.
${s+=" what he did"}.
${s+=" wrong"}.
${s} with mobile.`
)()
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

Comment: Nice approach I have "borrowed" it for my C# answer.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the rules of the game, but this function only works correctly if you're in a browser and using the pre tag innertext like you did. So isn't that more than 102 bytes, since it depends on the o.innerText= and the <pre id="o"> and actually getting ahold of the element?

Comment: @Paul I know this is old but, an anonymous function is acceptable form of I/O as an entry, so as long as it returns the expected data, it doesn't need to display it directly.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>95</s> 86 bytes

```
:`
Steve Ballmer still does not know.
:`.$
 what he did.
:`.$
 wrong.
.$
 with mobile.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcgxDoAgDAXQnVP8wZkDMHoFLwCGRhoLTaCR42Pi4PbyOhm3tFaI7jB6CHsSqdQxjEWQlQaaGu6m07sQ/eYwSzIUQub8V9d2efeRraDqyUJ@rRc) Edit: Saved 9 bytes by switching from outputting parts of the whole string to building up the string in pieces. The `` :` `` is needed on the first three stages to make them output.

Comment: ooh that's clever, deleting everything between the `w` and `e`, then deleting everything between the `wr` and `e`, then `wi` and `e`. Not super golfy due to Retina's newline-iness, but definitely cool nontheless

Comment: @Mayube Turned out to be not very golfy at all, so I've switched methods. (Still not as cool as Martin Ender's answer though.)

Comment: Ugh, this is still worse than @Leo's Retina Kolmogorov golfer, which finds an 82-byte answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>124</s> 122 bytes

```c
#define A"Steve Ballmer still does not know"
#define B".\n"A" what he did"
f(){puts(A B B" wrong"B" wrong with mobile.");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxTsQwEER7f8XI1yQIIvogpOQXKIHC2HvxCmeN7M2lON23B4N0Uz3NPI1/Wrw/Tiw@bYHwUjVwHuLrcQp0ZiFMsG9KF8LsUlqpoCqnhJCpQrLiW/Juzd2eYYcPsZPFHp0iEgIHa85df/3ZtHZTM@Y2liyLvQN21og1f3Giwfbj7WBRrI6l@wNXFv8IH12Bz1IVD625vH/25mrQ0s7HfyikWxE8j@Zmjl8)

Comment: You can remove the spaces between `A` and `B`, and the strings that define them.

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <s>158</s> <s>128</s> <s>120</s> 114 bytes

```c#
()=>{var s="Steve Ballmer still does not know";return s+$@".
{s+=" what he did"}.
{s+=" wrong"}.
 with mobile.";};
```

*Saved 30 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen.*
*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.*

---

Version using sub-stringing for 120 bytes:

```c#
s=n=>"Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile".Substring(0,n)+".\n";()=>s(33)+s(45)+s(51)+s(63);
```

Version borrowed from @KevinCruijssen for 128 bytes:

```c#
()=>{string t="Steve Ballmer still does not know",d=".\n";return t+d+(t+=" what he did")+d+(t+=" wrong")+d+t+" with mobile"+d;};
```

Version using looping for 158 bytes:

```c#
()=>{var r="";for(int i=0;++i<5;)r+=$"Steve Ballmer still does not know{(i>1?$" what he did{(i>2?$" wrong{(i>3?" with mobile":"")}":"")}":"")}.\n";return r;};
```

Simple approach using ternary statements to in a loop to append the new parts onto the string each time.

Comment: As an aside, it's worth noting that this only works for `C# >= 6` as earlier versions don't have interpolated strings

Comment: @Mayube True, but I'm golfing this to use Kevin's approach at the moment as that is a lot better than mine haha

Comment: Gotta golf 2 more bytes so you can beat the java answer D:

Comment: @Mayube The Java answers usually beat C# because they don't include a trailing semi-colon. Is always annoying!

Comment: @Mayube Done it, for the time being at least...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Nice approach +1. I don't think I can outgolf this in Java, because you can do `()=>` as inner method, and I have to define the entire lambda as well which raises the byte-count by a lot.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Well I'm compiling to two separate anonymous functions where one just calls the other, I'd assume you could use that idea too.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <s>111</s> <s>109</s> 107 bytes

```
a=(Steve Ballmer still does not know "what he did" wrong with\ mobile)
for i in {6..9};{ echo ${a[@]::i}.;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsIwEAbg3af4KR10ySjYIoiv4FgdruY0h2kOkmCGkGdPv2@l5Hqn6/GR@c@4k/cbR6Qs3sMqJwTN@AUtGIqjDMewYgeUqOGLItk9sekqnk@Hj0YIJKCejbm0uYLfTjFWWm6vaZJm5tb7Dg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>65</s> <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

Contains a few characters that won't display here; follow the link below to see the full code.

```
`Sve Ba¥´r Ð]l º not know
 Ø  ¹d
 Ùg
 ØP ¶ßè`£'.iP±X}R
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YFOSdmUgQmGltHIg0F1sILqDIG5vdCBrbm93CiDYiSCUILlkCiDZkWcKINhQILbf6GCjJy5pULFYfVI=&input=)

- <s>3</s> 4 bytes saved thanks to [ETH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions), plus another 4 with some prompting.

---

### Explanation

Everything between the 2 backticks is a compressed string of the following:

```
Steve Ballmer still does not know
 what he did
 wrong
 with mobile
```

```
`...`             :Decompress the string.
     £       }R   :Map over the each line X in the string
         P±X      :   Append X to P (initially the empty string)
      '.i         :   Prepend that to the string "."
```

Comment: Nice. You can save some bytes by doing ```[`Sve Ba¥´r Ð]l º not know`` Ø  ¹d`` Ùg`` ØP ¶ßè.`]m@P+=X}```, then a couple more bytes that involves removing the `[` and `]` (I'll let you figure that one out).

Comment: Nice one, @ETHproductions. Took me a couple of minutes to decipher that between the compression and characters SE doesn't display but I got there and now I think I see the other saving you're hinting at too.

Comment: You may be better off if you remove the splitting and joining, and instead do `£P±X +'.}R` at the end

Comment: @ETHproductions, it still comes in at 61 bytes, but it's definitely neater; gets rid of the need for the trailing newline. EDIT: Oh, wait, no, I can save 1 byte with that approach :)

Answer (score 3):

## Fission, <s>299</s> <s>291</s> 269 bytes

```
MN"."                             ]              ]        ]
                                  W$]            W$$]     W$$$]
R"Steve Ballmer still does not know"%[" what he did"%[" wrong"%[" with mobile.";
                                    [W              [W        [W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc6hDsJAEIRh36eYbIqtwOLwIECcaCpKbuE2bG@T3qV9/KOiQZAAHfXnU3OXlMTivpTTmRrCv3U/pauwYW3tPuEtS9auutA188Q49qoDj0hZVOGNE6JlPKPNtENLmEOfERhe/AqjxceakgMGu4lyQ4dtz@C@wpKlvAA)

Finally a 2D language I understand!

#### Explanation

Program spawns an atom with 1 mass and 0 energy (a `1:0` atom)at the `R` on line 3, and begins moving to the right.

`"Steve Ballmer still does not know"` prints each character.

`%` moves the atom up if it has 0 energy, or decrements it's energy and moves it down.

`]` moves the atom to the left, `$` increments the atom's energy, `W` moves the atom up.

Once the atom is on the top row, it moves to the left, until it reaches `"."`, which prints a period, `N`, which prints a newline, and finally `M`, which moves the atom down to the `R` again, which subsequently moves the atom to the right.

Each loop the atom's energy is one higher, meaning it will pass through one more `%`. After the 4th loop it reaches the `;` at the end of the third line, which destroys the atom. The program terminates once all atoms are destroyed.

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Comment: @Shaggy will do

Comment: You can compress the top a lot more: [209 bytes](https://tio.run/##jcexDoJAEEXRnq94mWBLYWtnr4UWFBsKzA7uxGEnYSfy@UtBjfFW90xSilg@13q7U0f4WTscuR2aBz2dv4zrqDrzguKiimhckM3xybbSKRDWNDoSI0rcvVh@7yeeMNtLlDu6NPij0B859LVu).

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 79 keystrokes

```
iSteve Ballmer still does not know.<CR><C-x><C-l><Backspace> what he did.<CR><C-x><C-l><Backspace> wrong.<CR><C-x><C-l><Left> with mobile
```

`<C-x><C-l>` auto-completes with the previous line. Alternatively you can replace every occurrence of `<CR><C-x><C-l>` with `<Esc>o<C-a>`

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 79 bytes

```
4{)"Steve Ballmer still does not know
hat he did
rong
ith mobile"N/<" w"*'.+N}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/36RaUym4JLUsVcEpMScnN7VIobgkMydHISU/tVghL79EITsvv5wrI7FEISNVISUzhasoPy@dK7MkQyE3PykzJ1XJT99GSaFcSUtdT9uvVvX/fwA)

Comment: wow, interesting pattern find

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 94 bytes

```
"!-3Z".bytes{|i|puts"Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile"[0,i]+?.}
```

Iterates through the 4 characters in the first string, converting each to its ascii value `n` and outputting the first `n` characters of the second string each time. It really does not matter what the last character of the first string is, so long as its ascii value is equal or greater than the length of the second string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 100 bytes

```
for i in " ,2>":echo "Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile"[0..i.int],"."
```

here the same in more readable code:

```
const str = "Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile"

for i in [32, 44, 50, 62]:
  echo(str[0..i], ".")
```

The language has string slicing and inclusive upper bounds. The rest should explain itself if you know programming.

Comment: 99 bytes: `for i in " ,2>":"Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile"[0..i.int].echo"."`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 116 Bytes

```php
for(;$i<4;)echo"Steve Ballmer still does not know",["",$t=" what he did",$t.=" wrong","$t with mobile"][+$i++],".
```

";

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixDsIgEADQ3a@4XBg0kE5u1Jj4C45NhyqnXKQcoRf5fLTLG16JpY/X8vcl9egNj2d/omcUvCt9CW5LSitV2JRTgiC0QRaFT5aGbkJ0Ri8ILS4KkSBw2GfYq0p@o0Oj0FgjrPLgRDhP1rC1s8PhgL73Hw)

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/tree/8971b53470a627e82dc99741b7acbabf89ea7b28/P5Parser), 42 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
⁹⁴<>‘υG‘Γω/w¹‘O‛Æw▓½0H(æ█◄K∆2Ξgh‘4{Tļ.@+;+
```

Explanation:

```
..‘                    push "with mobile"
   ..‘                 push "wrong"
      ..‘              push "what he did"
         ..‘           push "Steve Ballmer still does not know"
            4{         4 times do
              T          output, not popping the top of stack
               ļ.        output "."
                 @+      append a space to the top thing in stack
                   ;+    reverse add (adding the next part to the top thing in stack)
```

Comment: How do you use SOGL? I have installed Processing and all of the versions, although I can't figure out how you would run it.

Comment: open up the "P5Parser" with no version labels, and in it's folder in `data/p.sogl` paste the code. Then running the processing code should run it and the output should be in the console

Comment: Tried to run your code, but it doesn't have any output... `./processing-java --sketch=../SOGL/P5Parser --run p.sogl ""`

Comment: It works for me. Try giving it the full path instead of `p.sogl`. if there's nothing in STDOUT or `P5Parser/output.txt`, I don't know.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/GolfingSuccess/6f4f752b26f8fe88ad71a3720824934d) is the output for me, separated into STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: Content of file `/home/erik/Desktop.bak/Desktop/SOGL/P5Parser/data/p.sogl` is `⁹⁴<>‘υG‘Γω/w¹‘O‛Æw▓½0H(æ█◄K∆2Ξgh‘4{Tļ.@+;+`. `/home/erik/Desktop` is symlink to `/home/erik/Desktop.bak/Desktop`. Oh and preprocessor actually contains the code, output is different from that of an empty file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59996/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-dzaima).

Comment: What encoding do you save the file in? I did store it in UTF8 and it is 73 Bytes. Therefore I have to count your claim to have only 73 bytes as wrong.

Comment: @Arne You'd have to save it in [SOGLs encoding](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md). With it there is a 1-to-1 from a byte to a character. Trough right now there isn't a converter

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 49 bytes

```
“ṬċḌ)⁹œḃṣ⁷Ṅḋ%W3Œƭ;ḷẓ“¡=~Ṃ©N|ȯ“¡ṭṂ“CṬṀWỌ»ḣJK;¥€”.Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO9cc6X64o0fzUePOo5Mf7mh@uHPxo8btD3e2PNzRrRpufHTSsbXWD3dsf7hrMlD1oYW2dQ93Nh1a6VdzYj2Y/3DnWqAAkOkMNOnhzobwh7t7Du1@uGOxl7f1oaWPmtY8apirF/n/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>140</s> 127 bytes

```
import."fmt"
func f(){for _,i:=range"!-3?"{Println("Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile"[:i]+".")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc5NDoIwEEDhPacYZwVR2bgjMSaewMSlMaZCWya0M6SMdkE4O/68C3zPyzqadjDeQjTEK8VRktboomLhXtyCK6vZSYLHjppjMuwtbvaHE86XRKyBS7yqfVs4mxCiTTAphQCd2AlYFAaWDLk3Cr2FjjrISdhDJu0hypOCxVtD9y3WWC3L@id/J2UFcwHfvn6xrB8)

Answer (score 2):

## Sed, 96

```
s/^/Steve Ballmer still does not know./p
s/\./ what he did./p
s/\./ wrong./p
s/\./ with mobile./
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TcjBDYAgDAXQu1P8CegOruDVmGBohFiooY2Mj1eP7xmnOY0O2pxfxhpFKneYFxEkZUNTx910BHoWoz0QRo6OzEgl/bJru34snlH1LMKB5vwA).

Implicit newline input given, as per [this meta-question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5476/are-languages-like-sed-exempt-from-no-input-rules).

Comment: You can get 92 bytes by removing the second two `\.`s

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>92</s> 91 bytes

```bash
printf 'Steve Ballmer still does not %s.
' know{,' what he did'{,\ wrong{,\ with\ mobile}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcYxDsMgDAXQvaf4S8US5RC9QtcsIJxgxeAIrDBEnJ1KfdMLvqU5r8rFdriv0U34eJFMFc1YBFGpoajh3daXw1m0P4tDT96QCJGje5YNvWo5/mFLG7IGFhpjzPkD)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript (ES6, no browser dependencies) 154 Bytes

```
(s='Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile.')=>{
  let l=s.slice.bind(s)
  return `${l(0,33).\n${l(0,45)}.\n${l(0,51)}.\n${s}`
}
```

The other ES6 solution requires (and doesn't account for) the use of html and html element APIs.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>113</s> 112 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

```c
f(c){for(c=0;write(1,"Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile","!-3?"[c++]);puts("."));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDsIgEADQtZxiZAVpazQuiTHxCi6NC4ShJfIxMMqi6dnxPTPNxvTuhJGry0WYy1G14gnFaeR3wh/CTYcQsUAlHwLYjBVSJnin3KAtmmBBsN5CKznN0DwtEPPLB@Qj30/nK3@YYXhK9flSFfzApVRbj9onIdnKdk5Ixbb@Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 81 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
↑1⌽¨,\'.Steve Ballmer still does not know' ' what he did' ' wrong' ' with mobile'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jtomGj3r2HlqhE6OuF1ySWpaq4JSYk5ObWqRQXJKZk6OQkp9arJCXX6KQnZdfrq6grlCekViikJGqkJKZAuYW5eelgxmZJRkKuflJmTmp6iCz/6cBAA)

One the very right, we have a list of strings.

`,\` cumulative concatenation

`1⌽¨` cyclically rotate each one step left (puts the periods at the ends)

`↑` mix the list of strings into a character matrix

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```
Ａ⟦⟧βＦ⪪”↓/‘ZQ≔'Ｗε}÷＆’/↗∧μ~⎇²~ηρπ‖¢β\`σuσＩ⌀δ#″:§▶¬QγγＱＺ–” w⁺⪫⊞Ｏβι w¦.¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxDsIgFAXQWb/ihokmrT/gVEcXm3RUB1qwvEh5DTzL56OJ@zmzN2lmE2rtc6Yl6vuzxdQcX5ygxy2QaDWK2x0uJoTVJWShEGDZZUQWvCMXFG8E3sGSRUkcFxQSj5UnCk5BoaimOR6GRFF0b62@MkU9fLK/bS4Z4aQnUPOHLdTpEX/hXGvt9trl8AU) Link is to verbose version of code, with some separators omitted because deverbosifier can't do it automatically. This is basically a port of @KevinCruijssen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>108</s> 104 bytes

```
"Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile"~StringTake~#~Print~"."&/@{33,45,51,63}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZNCsIwEAbQq3xEcBUUiXUtnkCoF0jN0AzNDySDWUhz9ehbvWjF87uOoWahD@FhQ4hUUIVDgMtUkbJgS7mheSvwBMcOreS0orF4xLxwINVnKZzWl92oH/rzf@nqpI7n@9cYfZ30dNE3s4/xAw)

*-4 bytes from Martin*

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 135 bytes

```
".wonk ton seod llits remllaB evetS"\
l?!\o99+2*1./"h tahw  "32p10pao     \
52p\".did e"/"   "53p33p
  /\".gnorw"/
1p/\".elibom htiw;"3
```

This basically goes through the string, prints then replaces the fullstop and conditionals with spaces to keep moving along the code.

It may be best to visualise it using the below ><> pond link;

[><> pond!](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYmxDsIgGAZ3nuLzHzUpFtKhcTDxFVxZMKAQaX9SiDw@trfd3TuW0DsNjdcvKq8onh1SirVg80tK9gH/8/VJRqT7yfA8X9R5HCQFVBsaQFrl8Zot48CISWVDg4sOniTtiSadtc4CkPv4rLw1kmLMh/kUX7wg1NhupHv/Aw)

Comment: It never occurred to me that `know` spelled backwards is `wonk`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Well, now you wonk

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 101 bytes

```
0..3|%{-join("Steve Ballmer still does not know"," what he did"," wrong"," with mobile")[0..$_]+"."}
```

Comment: [99 bytes, 5 years later :)](https://tio.run/##BcFbDsIgEAXQ/67ihtjEBxoNbRfgFroAU2UixCljgMqHde14zlsKxeSI@fiQSLUao7te9xc9mLX9btWY6UO4TswzRaTsmWGFEoJkvIIUFDdlOIL1FiVKeKL47DDL3TOptcW47HHG5rY7qJP61aapfw "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: I meant 97, but I missed the edit window

Answer (score 1):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 126 bytes

```
 \"elibom htiw \"10p";"15p
  "gnorw  "10p
  "did eh tahw \"11p
 \"wonk ton seod llits remllaB evetS\"12p04.
  l?!vo
oo00.>a"."
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 126 bytes

Two approaches, same length:

```matlab
printf('%s.\n',(s={'Steve Ballmer still does not know',' what he did',' wrong',' with mobile'}){1},[s{1:2}],[s{1:3}],[s{1:4}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcexCsIwEADQX7lFroUgVJ0EF3/BUTtEc5pgmpPc0Q4h3x6h4vYeP9TO1Nonh6TPDjeyvSU0nZwKXpRmgrONcaIMoiFGcEwCiRXeiRc0CIu3Cp7ABbc2c3qtCOph4nuIhLUvQzVXKcNxV8cf9n8c6ti39gU)

```matlab
s={'Steve Ballmer still does not know',' what he did',' wrong',' with mobile'};printf('%s.\n',s{1},[s{1:2}],[s{1:3}],[s{1:4}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcexCsIwEIDhV7lFrkIQrE6Ki6/QUTtEc5pgeifJ0Q4lzx6l4vLz/XJXO1Kt@TRjpzQSnG2MAyXIGmIEJ5SBReHFMqFBmLxV8AQuuGWT8HNBUA@D3EIkLMd3CqyPBld5c2U0ed4Wc/n20Jb@h90f@9Kva/0A)

I could make it 21 bytes shorter, if I steal Rod's approach, but that's no fun.

```matlab
for i=[33,45,51,63],disp(['Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile'(1:i),46]),end
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB / Octave - 120 bytes

```
a=[];s={'Steve Ballmer still does not know',' what he did',' wrong',' with mobile'};for i=s,a=[a i{1}];disp([a '.']);end
```

Logic is to start off with an empty string, then we have a cell array that contains the base string as the first element followed by the additions for the other elements.  Note that each additional component has a space prepended.  We then iterate through the cell array, and at each iteration we concatenate with a component and display the string to the user adding a period at the end.

We get:

```
>> a=[];s={'Steve Ballmer still does not know',' what he did',' wrong',' with mobile'};for i=s,a=[a i{1}];disp([a '.']);end
Steve Ballmer still does not know.
Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did.
Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong.
Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile.
```

## Try it online!

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_octave_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRGZoWFJ1Z3NaNTQ

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 90 bytes

```
"$_.".say for [\,] 'Steve Ballmer still does not know','what he did','wrong','with mobile'
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Perl**](http://perl.org), 98 bytes

```
for('Steve Ballmer still does not know',' what he did',' wrong',' with mobile'){$s.=$_;say "$s."}
```

(Run via perl -M5.10.1 ... so that "say" will be recognized)

Comment: According to [J B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/199/j-b)'s [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5130), you can rewrite it as `say$s.="$_."for'Steve Ballmer …`.

Comment: [You can shrink to 89 bytes with this](https://tio.run/##HccxDsIwDADAr1hWxxKVoSMLOxMPQEExxMKNq9hqxecxUre7lbrMEZa/g6XL8Bgx4Us73p02gmuWhTqYswgUJYOmDp@mO44Ie80OlaBwOdq1vQ@wV1j0yUIY8dPVWZvF6Tan6Tz9AQ "Perl 5 – Try It Online"), but can't think of much more to do to shrink it!

Comment: Down to 85! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDsIwDAXQq3xFXWnK0JGFnYkLEBSriXDjKraIKiGO3vS9jSrPvbun0ZdwD7xShVpmRhRSFDF8ijS0FAyJEHNEq1IWtGwJq7wzk7v91aP9Bq9hd8NrdH6h2vshm2Up2i@PeZyu0wk "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 82 bytes

```
ABCC with mobile.
C
B wrong
B
.¶A what he did
A
Steve Ballmer still does not know
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRDYAgDAXA/07xJnAHYAQnwNBIY6EJNrKZA7gY3g126XktCjElTPGKZocob5QoYg7rJ0Xavjdg1uyojCKFAu3ODyNm1cYDt4sqivGNbo6r21zrBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 145 bytes

```rust
||{for i in b"!-3?"{println!("{}.",&"Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile".to_owned().get(..*i as usize).unwrap());}};
```

Inspired by [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123978).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsIwEAXQtZ7im4Ukotm4FBG8ggeQlE7tYDqRZGrAtmev7@Wx6NoJhsBiHabtJpKiu67zPHUpg8GCxuxO55uZPplFo@ysmRZvjnvzUPoS7iHGgTKKcoxoExVIUrwlVdQ@KHpCyy1qTvJCZe0xpIYjGa/pmapQa51/kVrvD4xQMBb@kfOj1Bw@1rnLslzWzrpl/QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 99 bytes

Generate the 4 desired strings with `cumprod` (`*` is string concatenation). Tack on a period with a broadcasted string concatenation `.*` and print all elements in the list with a broadcasted call `println.`.

```julia
println.(cumprod(["Steve Balmer still does not know"," what he did"," wrong"," with mobile"]).*".")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HccxDsIwDAXQq3x5ahHKyAG4AiNiCMQiBseuUpceP0jd3vtsKvkyxtLFQi1Nr60t3ct0p1vwj3HN2rhjDVFFcV5hHvia73Qm7DUHKqNIOdrd3gckKpo/RZkeczpRonmMPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Unix TMG](https://github.com/amakukha/tmg), 145 bytes

```
p:parse(b)b:=(1){<Steve Ballmer still does not know>$1<.>*}=(1){1({< what he did>$1})}=(1){1({< wrong>$1})}={3({})2({})1({})1({< with mobile>})};
```

With some white spaces:

```
p:parse(b)
b:=(1){<Steve Ballmer still does not know>$1<.>*}
  =(1){1({< what he did>$1})} 
  =(1){1({< wrong>$1})}
  ={3({}) 2({}) 1({}) 1({< with mobile>})};
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 43 bytes

```
”™¸ïßmer”“„â‚à€–ƒ€“…€À€½ƒ§'–Ñ„€Ž†©)η¦ðý'.«»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRy2LDu04vP7w/NzUIhC3Yc6jhnmHFz1qmHV4waOmNY8aJh@bBKaB4suAjMMNQOLQ3mOTDi1XB0oenghUDhQ5uvdRw4JDKzXPbT@07PCGw3vV9Q6tPrT7/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 1507 bytes

```
{{i}dd}iiic{iii}iiic{d}dddddc{ii}dddc{dd}iiic{{d}iii}ic{iii}iiiic{iii}ic{i}iccic{d}iic{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}iiicic{d}dciiicc{{d}iii}ddddddc{{i}ddd}ddc{i}ic{d}c{i}iiiic{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dd}ddciciiiiic{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiciiicic{i}ddc{{d}iii}dddc{ddd}ddddddc{{i}ddd}iiic{iii}iiic{d}dddddc{ii}dddc{dd}iiic{{d}iii}ic{iii}iiiic{iii}ic{i}iccic{d}iic{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}iiicic{d}dciiicc{{d}iii}ddddddc{{i}ddd}ddc{i}ic{d}c{i}iiiic{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dd}ddciciiiiic{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiciiicic{i}ddc{{d}i}iiic{{i}d}dddc{d}dddddc{d}iiic{ii}dc{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iicdddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}ddciiiiicdddddc{ddddd}ddddc{ddd}ddddddc{{i}ddd}iiic{iii}iiic{d}dddddc{ii}dddc{dd}iiic{{d}iii}ic{iii}iiiic{iii}ic{i}iccic{d}iic{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}iiicic{d}dciiicc{{d}iii}ddddddc{{i}ddd}ddc{i}ic{d}c{i}iiiic{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dd}ddciciiiiic{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiciiicic{i}ddc{{d}i}iiic{{i}d}dddc{d}dddddc{d}iiic{ii}dc{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iicdddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}ddciiiiicdddddc{{d}iii}iic{{i}d}dddcdddddcdddcdc{d}iiic{dddddd}iiic{ddd}ddddddc{{i}ddd}iiic{iii}iiic{d}dddddc{ii}dddc{dd}iiic{{d}iii}ic{iii}iiiic{iii}ic{i}iccic{d}iic{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}iiicic{d}dciiicc{{d}iii}ddddddc{{i}ddd}ddc{i}ic{d}c{i}iiiic{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dd}ddciciiiiic{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiciiicic{i}ddc{{d}i}iiic{{i}d}dddc{d}dddddc{d}iiic{ii}dc{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iicdddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}ddciiiiicdddddc{{d}iii}iic{{i}d}dddcdddddcdddcdc{d}iiic{{d}iii}dc{{i}d}dddc{d}ddddc{i}ic{d}ddc{{d}iii}ddc{{i}dd}dddciic{d}dddc{i}dddciiic{d}iiic{ddddd}dddddc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VTLDsIwDPsiPgrVIHLescq3l7zbgjgiDmzS2ixJ7diVhtsVdzoelzF6JwaYiFqXxQNISh7NsO3Z0W3n2ZuRbLI0O0v@Vf2sCJPG8ZuGBYjgsy7YAQMFB9SCVWASkcJsxQnilWCMIYpNJeGV9n9MiMEkEdJSa5nA@IDXsDhJ67TOlUBIg0@rv2x1Nqw0XrK3mFx0xeeV/P5KUvv7NKV@@29N3UoYvS7N7dzuOmSN8QQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>38</s> 37 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¥úσÆ}≡ër↑←â .M)↨\7╒°1╕J°Y¥₧iC+F.ifd┼$
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9da3e5927df08972181b83202e4d29175c37d5f831b84af8599d9e69432b462e696664c524&i=&a=1)

Comment: should be 37 removing the swap `s`

Comment: Quite right.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Braingolf, <s>139</s> 108 bytes

```
"Steve Ballmer still does not know
."VRMM!&@v!&@R" what he did"!&@v!&@R" wrong"!&@v!&@R " with mobile"&@v&@R
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 95 bytes

```
?@Steve Ballmer still does not know`+@.`?A+@ what he did`+B?A+C+@ wrong`+B?A+C+D+@ with mobile.
```

This makes every part of the output into a separate string literal, where 'A$' holds `Steve Ballmer still does not know`, and then repeatedly prints 'A$', followed by 'B$' (a period) or the next literal.

Chopping the original string into substrings takes just a byte more (96 bytes):

```
?B,34|+@.`?_sB,46|+A?_sB,52|+A?@Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile.
```

Here, 'B$' holds the entire thing, and parts of it are subsequently shown using substring ('_s...|`). Note that 'A$' now holds the period. This allows the full sentence to be moved to the end of the program, so we can drop the closing backtick.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 115 bytes

```
puts [set S "Steve Ballmer still does not know"].\n[set h "$S what he did"].\n[set w $h\ wrong].\n$w\ with\ mobile.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYoxEsMgDAS/csNQ8wh/gdJ2YQeNYSIjj1Gi5xOSJt3e3uqDe79e2jA3UkS4qPQmTBvzSTeaFmYkoYYqimcVc2tY6q/OcD7C8jaQkEr6XwafF9gt9fg6b2MUHeqUvTCF3j8)

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 123 bytes

```
s='Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile'
w=6 9 10 12
do i=1 to 4
say subword(s,1,word(w,i)).
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## MSX-BASIC, 123 bytes

```
1s$="Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile":forx=1to4:readl:?left$(s$,l);".":next:data33,45,51,64
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure(script), 122 bytes

```
(print(apply str(interpose"\n"(reductions str"Steve Ballmer still does not know"[" what he did"" wrong"" with mobile"]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 98

```
K." w!ZÑ`±§ÑÔæý^àV;KæM×ü1A_4ÿ"J" what he did"A," wrong"" with mobile"=N\.+KN++KJNs[KJGN)s[KJGHN
```

The first string is a packed string

Answer (score 0):

## [Fission 2](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), <s>109</s> 107 bytes

```
R"Steve Ballmer still does not know"J2~~$$" what he did"J1~$" wrong"J0" with mobile."*
/0C+$$J1C+$$J2C@"."N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcgxDsIwDEDRnVNYViaQSpsTILplYKAnKIohFm4sNRbdcvUUWL6e/pNLYc2@tTtORh@C6yyy0ArFWASiUoGsBu@sGwZfq3MIW5oNEkHkiGGov7NqfmHov2JLsOiDhTo8Hs79eHIuDP/68YId3lrbAQ)

I was a little annoyed at the amount of whitespace in the [previous Fission answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124017/76162), so I decided to see if I could make it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 82 bytes

```
4,{"Steve Ballmer still does not know
 what he did
 wrong
 with mobile"n/\)<"."n}/
```

This can be considered "19 bytes" since that's the actual code.

`4,{"nnn"s/\)<"."n}/` are all the excess characters that actually make the code itself.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxDoMwDAXQnVN8ZUOqYOnI1Ct07QLEJVaNXSUWDIizB6ant5h8y5z577U@H0d4O22E1yiyUkZxFkE0KlBz/NT2BnsaHYkQOd7JpssNe8JqEwsF7T/tELqgZ1/rBQ)

Very happy with this. Splits along newlines, then adds the next element one at a time with a period until everything is printed. Lovely.

Explanation!

```
First of all, we have to acknowledge the string.
It's split along newlines right where we want the breaks to be.
This will be important.

For the explanation, our string is S.

4,{Sn/\)<"."n}/
4,              #Make an array [0 1 2 3]
  {          }/ #For each of those elements...
   Sn/          #Take our string and split it along newlines
      \         #Move our number-element to the front of the stack
       )        #Increase it by 1
        <       #Look at a number of parts of the split string eq. to that num
         "."    #Put a period after
            n   #Newline
                #Implicit "print the stack" at the end of creation. No quotes.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 97 bytes

```python
["Steve Ballmer still does not know what he did wrong with mobile"[:i]+"."for i in [33,45,51,63]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCgIxDAXQq3y6tQhSx4VLr@CydDHSaIOZRDrB4unre5@fN9M0Zw53py/htops1LE7i6Aa7VBzvNUGRlsdjVC5YnTTFwZ7w2YPFgr5yuUQjuFpHQxW5JTieYnLKV5SKXP@AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `oj`, <s>124</s> <s>58</s> 50 bytes

```
`æ⁽ æ∴Ǐ₇ ⟑∵ ƛ∪ λ† ¬λ λ⟨ he ¬ṙ ↔Ẏ λ» ∨⁺`»→⇩d»₆τẎ\.+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJvaiIsIiIsImDDpuKBvSDDpuKItMeP4oKHIOKfkeKItSDGm+KIqiDOu+KAoCDCrM67IM674p+oIGhlIMKs4bmZIOKGlOG6jiDOu8K7IOKIqOKBumDCu+KGkuKHqWTCu+KChs+E4bqOXFwuKyIsIiIsIiJd)

Comment: 50 bytes: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJvaiIsIiIsImDDpuKBvSDDpuKItMeP4oKHIOKfkeKItSDGm+KIqiDOu+KAoCDCrM67IM674p+oIGhlIMKs4bmZIOKGlOG6jiDOu8K7IOKIqOKBumDCu+KGkuKHqWTCu+KChs+E4bqOXFwuKyIsIiIsIiJd)