# Diagonal Alphabet To the Input

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, alphabet

Inspired by [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125117/diagonal-alphabet). For those marking this question as a duplicate I urge you to actually read the question to see that mine is a modification of the one linked. The one linked does not ask for an input and is to just print the alphabet diagonally.

**The Challenge**

Given an input between 1-26 inclusively, print the alphabet diagonally, but begin printing vertically at the index of the given input.

**Examples**

Given the input:

```
16
```

Your program should output:

```
a
 b
  c
   d
    e
     f
      g
       h
        i
         j
          k
           l
            m
             n
              o
               p
               q
               r
               s
               t
               u
               v
               w
               x
               y
               z
```

Input:

```
4
```

Output:

```
a
 b
  c
   d
   e
   f
   g
   h
   i
   j
   k
   l
   m
   n
   o
   p
   q
   r
   s
   t
   v
   w
   x
   y
   z
```

Input:

```
1
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

Input:

```
26
```

Output:

```
a
 b
  c
   d
    e
     f
      g
       h
        i
         j
          k
           l
            m
             n
              o
               p
                q
                 r
                  s
                   t
                    u
                     v
                      w
                       x
                        y
                         z
```

**Scoring**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Good luck!

Comment: May we choose to use either 0- or 1-indexing?

Comment: Is a consistent leading space acceptable?

Comment: Are trailing spaces acceptable?

Comment: May we use uppercase?

Comment: May we return a list of strings?

Comment: @Giuseppe sure, no problem!

Comment: @DomHastings yes, they are!

Comment: @Adám yes to both of your questions!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
↘✂β⁰Ｎ↓✂βη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R24xHc5rObXrUuOH9nnWP2iaDeee2//9vAgA)

#### How it works

```
↘✂β⁰Ｎ↓✂βη
 ✂β⁰Ｎ         the alphabet from position 0 to the input
↘               print diagonally, down and to the right
        ✂βη    the alphabet starting from the position of the input
       ↓        print downwards
```

This solution no longer works in the current version of Charcoal (most likely due to a bug fix), but the issue is resolved for 10 bytes with [`↘✂β⁰Ｎ↓✂βＩθ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R24xHc5rObXrUuOH9nnWP2iaDee/3rDy34/9/EwA).

Comment: I'm not sure why that works; it may be a bug that was introduced a couple of weeks ago. (You'd normally have to use `Ｉθ` instead of `η`.)

Comment: @Neil It seem broken today. Using Ｉθ solves it.

Comment: Save 1 byte by using `…βＮ` instead of `✂β⁰Ｎ`.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
AvNI<‚Wysú,
```

First time trying 05AB1E, so I'm open to tips.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fsczP0@ZRw6zwyuLDu3T@/zc0AwA)

If a zero-indexed input from `0` to `25` is allowed, this can be 10 bytes by omitting the `<`.

Comment: Niiice! Exactly what I got. I tried "lift" but it's not working as planned. I think that's pretty optimal :).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>61 58 57</s> 56 bytes

```
def f(i,j=0):exec"print(' '*~-i)[:j]+chr(97+j);j+=1;"*26
```

-3 bytes thanks to Rod

-2 more bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: [same answer, but with input/print to save few bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDU9eQKy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hM06qgKDOvRF1BXSs3M08jUydPUzs5o0gjU9vSXPP/f1MA)

Comment: @Pavel That wouldn't work since then `input` would be called every time the `for` loop iterates, even though there's only one line of input.

Comment: [57 bytes using exec](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1Mny9ZA0yq1IjVZqaAoM69EXUFdKzczTyNT11AnS1M7OaNIw9JcO0vTOkvb1tBaScvI7H@ahonmfwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDU9eQKy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hM06qgKDOvRENdQV0rUzPaKi9WOzmjSCNT29Jc8/9/UwA) using subscripting.

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1Mny9ZA0yq1IjVZqaAoM69EQ11BXatON1Mz2iorVjs5o0jD0lw7S9M6S9vW0FpJy8jsf5qGoZnmfwA)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES2017), <s>73</s> <s>72</s> <s>71</s> 66 bytes

*Saved some bytes thanks to @JustinMariner*

```
f=(n,x=26)=>x?f(n,x-1)+(x+9).toString(36).padStart(x<n?x:n)+`
`:''
```

Comment: This adds a `10` after `z` at the end due to having `++x` before `x.toString()`. Bugfixed and golfed to 68 bytes using `padStart`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##FctRCoMwDADQ/17EhM6C29iYs/MQXsCorSgllVpGbt@x9/92@tI5p@3I9USTCzXHxZXiLfBFbIP2I9312YPoF5och5w2XuH2QHPQMmRKGaTjXlpGPapR@//TDbZVpdR7jnzG4EyIK3i4I5byAw)

Comment: @JustinMariner Thanks, I think I might switch to ES8 for that...

Comment: Can you save anything by currying? `n=>g=(x=26)=>x?f(x-1)+(x+9).toString(36).padStart(x<n?x:n)+'\n':""`

Comment: @Shaggy Perhaps, I don't know if that type of currying is allowed though.

Comment: Ah, nuts, looks like [your proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11317/58974) to allow this is no longer a consensus :(

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>51</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
->n{(0..25).map{|x|(' '*x)[0,n-1]<<(x+97)}}
```

Returns a list of strings.

Looks like the Python guys were on to something with their subscripts. -5 bytes by taking inspiration from Mr. Xcoder's improvement of ppperry's solution.

Previous solution with `rjust` (51 bytes):

```
->n{i=0;(?a..?z).map{|c|c.rjust i+=n>c.ord-97?1:0}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>62</s> <s>50</s> 57 bytes

```python
x=input();n=m=1
exec"print'%*c'%(m,n+96);n+=1;m+=x>m;"*26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I2M6@gtERD0zrPNtfWkCu1IjVZqaAoM69EXVUrWV1VI1cnT9vSDCitbWtonattW2GXa62kZWT2/78pAA)

Steals heavily from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125144/65836) by Dennis.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>72</s> 68 bytes

```
^
z
{2=`
$`
}T`l`_l`^.
\D
$.`$* $&¶
\d+
$* 
s`( *)( +)(?=.*¶\1 $)
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/jquKq9rINoFLJYGrNiQhJyE@JyFOjyvGhUtFL0FFS0FF7dA2rpgUbS4gm6s4QUNBS1NDQVtTw95WT@vQthhDBRVNLhXD//9NAA) Output includes trailing whitespace. Save 1 byte by deleting the space before the `$` if zero-indexing is allowed. Edit: Saved 4 bytes by using @MartinEnder's alphabet generator. Explanation:

```
^
z
{2=`
$`
}T`l`_l`^.
```

Insert the alphabet.

```
\D
$.`$* $&¶
```

Diagonalise it.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the input to unary as spaces.

```
s`( *)( +)(?=.*¶\1 $)
$1
```

Trim overlong lines so that no line is longer than the blank line at the end.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>99</s> 89 bytes

*@MickeyT saved 10 bytes*

#### function

```
function(x)for(i in 1:26)cat(paste(c(rep(" ",min(x,i)),letters[i]),collapse=""),sep="\n")
```

#### demo

```
f <- function(x)for(i in 1:26)cat(paste(c(rep(" ",min(x,i)),letters[i]),collapse=""),sep="\n")
f(1)
f(10)
f(15)
f(26)
```

Comment: A couple of little savings.  Rather then the `ifelse` try `min`.  `print.noquote` can be replaced with `cat` with a `'\n'` in the paste.  The `\n` can be a straight carriage return. Curly braces for the function body can be dropped.

Comment: You can save some more by using `write` rather than `cat` and `paste`: `write(c(rep(" ",min(x,i)),letters[i]),"",26,,"")`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 103 bytes

```
(T=Table;a=Alphabet[];c=Column)[c/@{T[""<>{T[" ",i],a[[i]]},{i,#}],T[""<>{T[" ",#],a[[i]]},{i,#,26}]}]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>21</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
VlG+*d?>QNNQ@GN
```

Explanation:

```
VlG        For each character in the alphabet (G)
+          Concatenate...
 *d        Space (d) times...
   ?>QNNQ  Ternary; if Q (input) is less than N, return N, else Q
 @GN       The Nth character of the alphabet (G)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyzHXVsrxd4u0M8v0MHd7/9/QwMA)

Comment: Found some considerably shorter approaches, and I decided to post [my own answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139663/59487).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
26Ḷ«’⁶ẋżØaY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//MjbhuLbCq@KAmeKBtuG6i8W8w5hhWf///zQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 84 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(dotimes(i 26)(format t"~v,,,@a~%"(if(< i x)(1+ i)x)(code-char(+ i 97)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxCoAwEAS/cgjCHsZCC0Ww8CtnonhgiGgQK78e4zQDw9hdryMhYRc/O8HDcCGqXy4otR1jDaeXSLF4b2PMJG9ZQFeMpJTfpiLlbBvcUttNTuRAQ88/qek4fQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 52 bytes

Quite surprised nobody noticed the obvious approach was also as short as the others.

```python
lambda k:[(i*" ")[:k-1]+chr(i+97)for i in range(26)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdLDkAwEADQq0xsTAkJEqKJk2BRnzI@06aphdNXvN2zr98NV0F3Q7jUPS0KTtkjJRFEopdnVozpvDuktG2ENg4IiMEp3lYsazEG64g9xgPH@WGIUeN/Yvt4FL9Q1B8)

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda k:[min(k-1,i)*" "+chr(i+97)for i in range(26)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbKjo3M08jW9dQJ1NTS0lBSTs5o0gjU9vSXDMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcPITDP2f0FRZl6JhnpMnrpeVj5QX5oGiJ@ZV1BaoqEJAv8NzQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 12 bytes

```
…26⊃§×¦₵a+†ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9nYWlh///igKYyNuKKg8Knw5fCpuKCtWEr4oCg4bmj//8xNQ)

#### Explanation

```
…             Range 0..input-1
 26⊃          Repeat the last number enough times to make it have length 26
    §×¦       Turn each number into a string of that many spaces
       ₵a+†   Add the corresponding letter to each
           ṣ  Join with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```
f n=do m<-[1..26];([2..min n m]>>" ")++['`'..]!!m:"\n"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzYlXyHXRjfaUE/PyCzWWiPaSE8vNzNPIU8hN9bOTklBSVNbO1o9QV1PL1ZRMddKKSZP6X9uIlCBrUJBaUlwSZGCikKagsl/AA)

How it works

```
f n=                  -- input number is n
  do m<-[1..26]       -- for each m from [1..26], construct a string and concatenate
                      -- them into a single string. The string is:
   [2..min n m]>>" "  -- min(n,m)-1 spaces,
      ++              -- followed by
   ['`'..]!!m         -- the m-th char after `
      :               -- followed by
   "\n"               -- a newline
```

Edit: @Lynn saved 4 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: [You can save four bytes using do notation and ``['`'..]!!m``.](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzYlXyHXRjfaUE/PyCzWWkNdQd1GJdpITy83M08hTyE3VlNbO1o9QV1PL1ZRMddKKSZP6X9uIlDOVqGgtCS4pEhBRSFNweQ/AA)

Comment: @Lynn; Thanks! I always forget about do notation for lists.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 69 bytes

```java
n->{for(int a=0;a++<26;)System.out.printf("%"+(a<n?a:n)+"c%n",a+96);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BisIwFEX3fsWjICTEhsEBQVt14cqFK5fDLJ4xKantS0lehEH67Z2OzOrCuZdzW3xiGQZL7f0xDfnWeQOmw5Tggp7gtQD4p4mR53gGf4d@7sSVo6fm6xswNkm@pwDt7NOZfaddJsM@kD4FSrm3sT4T28bGAzjYT1QeXi5E4YkB9x8VKlWvN5W8/iS2vQ6Z9TD72YliWSiBNR1xR1IVZknFCtV2I6txqt6nTqMxdmDxKf/AuBinXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

-1 as OP has now clarified that returning a list of strings is fine.

Prompts for input.

```apl
⎕A↑¨⍨-⎕⌊⍳26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdJTMxPT8vMSck//@jtomP@qY6AqlDKx71rtAFch71dD3q3WxkBlL5XwEMEBq4DM24MMRMMIUMMYWMzAA)

`⍳26` first 26 strictly positive **ɩ**ntegers

`⎕⌊` minimum of input and those

`-` negate those

`⎕A↑⍨¨` for each letter of the **A**lphabet, take that many characters (from the rear, as all numbers are negative), padding with spaces as necessary

---

`↑` convert list of strings into matrix (only in TIO link to enable readable output)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Oliver*

```
;C£RiXiYmUÉ î
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0OjUmlYaVltVckg7g==&input=Mw==)

Comment: @Oliver Dang, I was tired...

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 72 bytes

```javascript
n=>[..."abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"].map((e,i)=>" ".repeat(i<n?i:n-1)+e)
```

Returns a list of strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctNDoIwEEDhfU8x6aqN0IRoXKjFg6AJFQYswrQC4k@4ezVxZdx@L68xkxmK3voxJldiqHQgnWZKKW5ORYlVfbbNpe3I@Ws/jLfp/ni@@FF1xguBkZU65cBVjx7NKOyO9nZDcSIXKMOWsSyJYBnBKoJk/Z0QdMoAoHA0uBZV62qBEub5R6qPqcZZyg@U/1XJ5Da8AQ)

Comment: May I ask why node.js? seems like valid normal JS

Comment: @Downgoat It's the TIO auto formatting

Comment: btw you can save bytes using `.padStart`

Comment: Wait nvm the way I was thinking basically makes it into ETH's answer

Comment: Switch to ES8 and save a byte with `padEnd` instead of `repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 67 bytes

```
SparseArray[x=#;{#,#~Min~x}->Alphabet[][[#]]&~Array~26,{26,#}," "]&
```

Returns a `SparseArray` of strings. To visualize, append `Grid@` in front.

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com)

#### Usage

```
Grid@SparseArray[x=#;{#,#~Min~x}->Alphabet[][[#]]&~Array~26,{26,#}," "]&[5]
```

> ```
> a
>  b
>   c
>    d
>     e
>     f
>     g
>      
>     ⋮
>    
>     z
> ```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda n:['%*c'%(min(i+1,n),i+97)for i in range(26)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBDoIwFAX3PcXbkLZQTdoYiCScBFhUpfqN/BLoxtNX4sI425nM8k6PyC6HbsgvP19uHtz2siivslAzsaLKGtaGqnOjQ1xBIMbq@T4pV@sxp2lLGzr0tjY4GVgDV49C/Npv0ArsLCtxghxYHp9xfwdFWv@bg0QJ1@QP)

I'm assuming a list of strings is fine...

Shortest I could get with recursion:

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:i<26and['%*c'%(min(i+1,n),i+97)]+f(n,i+1)or[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
z{ē.-.Hχ@*Ot
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=eiU3QiV1MDExMy4tLkgldTAzQzdAKk90,inputs=NA__)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>47</s> 39 bytes

```perl
$l=<>;say$"x($#i+=$#i<$l-1).$_ for a..z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lx9bGzro4sVJFqUJDRTlT2xZI2Kjk6Bpq6qnEK6TlFykk6ulV/f9v@i@/oCQzP6/4v66vqZ6BoQEA)

Comment: Nuce use of `$#i`. That might even be worth [adding as a separate tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5105/9365)!

Comment: Coming back to this after three years and noticed you can drop to 30 bytes using `-na`!: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FOVPb1iHTRsnBTUmnOLFSySFTJV4pLb9IIVFPr@r/f9N/@QUlmfl5xf918xIVdH1N9QwMDQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda n:[('%*c'%(i,i+96))[-n:]for i in range(1,27)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBDsIgEADvvGIvDVCpCdVgJOlLKAfUotvo0lAuvh4bD8a5zmSWd3kkOtQ4jPUZXpdbALJO8Ka98kagwt3ZSOk6sj6mDAhIkAPdJ6FVf5K@lmktKwzgtFFwVKAV9MYz9qu/gWWwsWSkIvhIfD8nJBEFSin/Vcehhe1bPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(;i<26;printf("%*c\n",i++<n?i:n,i+97));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jT7M6Lb9IwzrTxsjMuqAoM68kTUNJVSs5Jk9JJ1Nb2ybPPtMqD8iyNNfUtK79n5uYmaehqVDNpQAEaRqGZprWXLX/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 12 bytes

```
j.e+<*kdtQbG
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.e%2B%3C%2akdtQbG&input=16&debug=0)**

If lists of Strings are allowed, this can be shortened to [**11 bytes**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.e%2B%3C%2akdtQbG&input=16&debug=0):

```
.e+<*kdtQbG
```

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 12 bytes

```
VG+<*dxGNtQN
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VG%2B%3C%2adxGNtQN&input=16&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 14 bytes

```
jm+<*d;tQ@Gd26
```

**[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2B%3C%2ad%3BtQ%40Gd26&input=16&debug=0)**

If lists of Strings are allowed, this can be shortened to [**13 bytes**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2B%3C%2ad%3BtQ%40Gd26&input=16&debug=0):

```
m+<*d;tQ@Gd26
```

---

## How do these work?

Unlike most of the other answers, this maps / loops over the lowercase alphabet in all 3 solutions.

#### Explanation #1

```
j.e+<*kdtQbG - Full program.

 .e        G - Enumerated map over "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", with indexes k and values b.
     *kd     - Repeat a space a number of times equal to the letter's index.
    <   tQ   - Crop the spaces after the input.
   +      b  - Concatenate with the letter.
j            - (Optional): Join by newlines.
```

#### Explanation #2

```
VG+<*dxGNtQN  - Full program.

VG            - For N in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
      xGN     - Index of the letter in the alphabet.
    *d        - Repeat the space a number of times equal to the index above.
   <     tQ   - But crop anything higher than the input.
  +        N  - Append the letter (at the end)
```

#### Explanation #3

```
jm+<*d;tQ@Gd26 - Full program.

 m          26 - Map over [0...26) with a variable d.
    *d;        - Space repeated d times.
   <   tQ      - Crop anything whose length is higher than the input.
  +      @Gd   - Concatenate with the letter at that index in the alphabet.
j              - (Optional): Join by newlines.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 40 bytes

Assuming that a list of Strings is fine.

```python
k=>[(i*" ")[to~-k]+chr(i+97)for i:0..26]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/b1i5aI1NLSUFJM7okv043O1Y7OaNII1Pb0lwzLb9IIdPKQE/PyCz2f0FRZl6JhnpMnrpeVn5mnkaahqGZpqbmfwA)

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 49 bytes

As ASCII-art instead:

```python
k=>'\n'.join((i*" ")[to~-k]+chr(i+97)for i:0..26)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/b1k49Jk9dLys/M09DI1NLSUFJM7okv043O1Y7OaNII1Pb0lwzLb9IIdPKQE/PyEzzf0FRZl6JRpqGoZmm5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 66 + 18 bytes

```cs
n=>new int[26].Select((x,i)=>$"{(char)(i+97)}".PadLeft(i<n?i+1:n))
```

Byte count also includes

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBSwMxEIXv@RVj8ZDQutAiFd3uipRWxApiBQ/iIaZTO5BmNcnalmV/@5ptpXSt75LJzJd5jyh3pjKLVe7IfMB04zwuo2GmNSpPmXHRLRq0pGLWICZkvmLGjFyi@5QKf/usYBCktHQObrb1rlPLeelJwXdGM3iQZLjYjwq2L2uNc6MGZHwH7kYmX6KV7xoHztuQIE1hDkllktTgCgL02uu/RVOsA3O@7pBI0tNWwdVCWsGpfXkhylb0KGcTnHtOA3NN7e6VEaI6dIybAXZW9RE3@qsFaQTOwwASGIb/yTRGTxi2k0EuBJwkYHKtReNZ0bjVmvOQPKSyDutlQkTP2YSc5yIaZ3Yk1YKvIUn3Fi@WPG491kLER@uOsT9Qyf7D6@D3uDmEd2DJyqrbZ@esy3r9Hw)

This returns a collection of strings, one for each line. If it's not allowed, the answer will swell by 17 bytes for `string.Concat()` and `\n` inside string

Explanation:

```cs
n =>
    new int[26]                      // Create a new collection of size 26
    .Select((x, i) =>                // Replace its members with:
        $"{(char)(i + 97)}"          // String of an alphabet character corresponding to the index
        .PadLeft(i < n ? i + 1 : n)  // Add spaces to the left
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 14 bytes

```
26:tiXl2Y2oZ?c
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=26%3AtiXl2Y2oZ%3Fc&inputs=16&version=20.4.0)

**Explanation**

```
26      % number literal
:       % range; vector of equally spaced values [1...26]
t       % duplicate
i       % explicitly grab the input
Xl      % clamp the array to have a maximum value of the input
2Y2     % predefined literal: ['a'...'z']
o       % convert to a numeric array
Z?      % create sparse matrix using the first two inputs as the rows/columns 
        % and the letters 'a'...'z' as the values
c       % convert back to character and implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 bytes

**31 bytes code + 5 for `-i# -l`.**

**Note**: this takes input via `-i`, if that is unacceptable (since it's non-standard) I can remove.

```perl
$\.=$"x(--$^I>0),print for a..z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRs9WRalCQ1dXJc7TzkBTp6AoM69EIS2/SCFRT6/q//9/@QUlmfl5xf91Mw3NFHRzAA)

#### Explanation

For this I'm abusing the special variable `$\` which is automatically printed after each call to `print`, to store the next line's indentation. Using the flag `-l` (which enables line ending processing), `$\` is pre-initialised to `"\n"` so we append a space each time we process an element in the range `a..z`, as long as `--$^I` isn't less than `0`. Using `$^I` (via the `-i` commandline flag) means I don't need to store input separately, but it's bit of a stretch as its not the usual way to accept input in Perl. Since the postfix `for` loop stores the current item in `$_`, we don't need any arguments to `print` (`$_` is automatically `print`ed and `$\` is automatically appended) so we just call it each iteration, appending spaces as we go to get the desired output. This does append trailing spaces though, which @[SpookyGengar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72476/spookygengar) has allowed.

Thanks to @[Xcali](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72767/xcali) for pointing out an oversight!

Comment: Are you off by one here?  Based on the examples, it looks like an input of 4 should have `d` and `e` vertically aligned.

Comment: @Xcali Oops! Yeah! Change to pre-decrement instead, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 60 bytes

```
f n=unlines$scanl(\p c->take(n-1)(p>>" ")++[c])"a"['b'..'z']
```

This is a function that returns the output as a String.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7Y0LyczL7VYpTg5MS9HI6ZAIVnXriQxO1UjT9dQU6PAzk5JQUlTWzs6OVZTKVEpWj1JXU9PvUo99n9uYmaegq1CSj6XgkJBaUlwSZFPnoKKQpqCyX8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 1.8 (without Lambda), 98 Bytes

```java
void m(int i){int c=0,o=97;String s="";for(;c++<26;s+=c<i?" ":"")System.out.println(s+(char)o++);}
```

The logic is straightforward. Provides no input data validation, very bad!

- Update: Function only! Thank you to @Olivier Grégoire

Comment: To spare some bytes, use `for(;c++<26;s+=c<i?" ":"")System.out.println(s+(char)o++);` Also, you can write only a function, or a lambda instead of a full program.

Comment: If I were to include only the body of a function, then how would the reader know what `a[0]` refers to? I think snippets are not fair if they do not compile; the challenge is just as interesting with a language rich in constructs.

Comment: Hello! I did say a function or a lambda, not a snippet. ;-) So you can write `void f(int i){...}` (no static needed) or `i->{...}` instead of your whole program. See [all Java tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java). See [my answer for this same challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139780/16236), as example. Have fun on the site! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1{(&[x-1;til 26]#'" "),'.Q.a};
```

**Example:**

```
q)-1{(&[x-1;til 26]#'" "),'.Q.a}16;
a
 b
  c
   d
    e
     f
      g
       h
        i
         j
          k
           l
            m
             n
              o
               p
               q
               r
               s
               t
               u
               v
               w
               x
               y
               z
```

**Explanation:**

Create a list of spaces (26) up to the length of the minimum of the input and the range of `0..25`), join with each letter of the alphabet, print to stdout.

```
-1{(&[x-1;til 26]#'" "),'.Q.a}; / solution
-1                            ; / print result to stdout and swallow return
  {                          }  / lambda function
                         .Q.a   / "abcd..xyz"
                       ,'       / concatenate (,) each
   (                  )         / do all this together
    &[   ;      ]               / minimum of each 
      x-1                       / implicit input (e.g. 10) minus 1 (e.g. 9)
          til 26                / 0 1 2 ... 23 24 25
                   '#" "        / take " " each number of times (0 1 2 )
```

**Notes:**

- -2 bytes by rejigging the brackets

Comment: While I couldn't find a shorter `q` answer, the following is only 22 bytes in `k4`: `{-1(-x&1+!26)$'$.Q.a;}`.

Comment: don't think you need the `'`? `{-1(-x&1+!26)$$.Q.a;}` for 21 bytes.

Comment: Ooh, good catch! Did not realize `$` (pad) accepts a list left-hand argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), <s>79</s> 70 bytes

The code outputs the required text and a trailing newline.

```
{@forfrom"a"to"z"}{@echols,_}{@inca}{@ifa is lowerargv.0}{@sets s," "}
```

**Ungolfed**:

```
{@for letter from "a" to "z"}
    {@echo spaces, letter, EOL} {@// same as echol}
    {@inc by 1 index} {@// sets to 1 if it doesn't exist}
    {@if index is lower than argv.0}
        {@// creates an array like [[[...], " "], " "]}
        {@set spaces spaces, " "}
    {@/} {@//not required}
{@/} {@// not required}
```

You can try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0ee99464f463d23072ff5d5be7dbd3a532f9c7c

(Old version: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a60e11b9dd2dcd54a84c11937f1918f26e0adcfa)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>66</s> 60 bytes

```powershell
param($a)65..90|%{" "*(($b=$_-65),($a-1))[$b-ge$a]+[char]$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVR08xUT8/SoEa1WklBSUtDQyXJViVe18xUUwcoqWuoqRmtkqSbnqqSGKsdnZyRWBSrEl/7//9/QzMA)

Loops through the alphabet, each iteration using string multiplication to prepend the appropriate number of spaces (chosen using a pesudo-ternary `(,)[]`), then string-concatenates with the current character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 6 bytes

```
G\xb1oh->
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=47+B1+6F+68+2D+3E&input=4&warnings=0&hex=1)

```
          - o = 0
G         -  alphabet
 \xb1     - for i in ^: (1 byte, pretty prints)
     oh   -    (o++)+1
       -  -   " "*^ + i
        > -  ^[input:]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 50 bytes

```bash
for c in {A..Z};{ printf "%$[++i<$1?i:$1]s\n" $c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCFZITNPodpRTy@q1rpaoaAoM68kTUFJVSVaWzvTRsXQPtNKxTC2OCZPSUEl2br2////hmYA)

Takes input as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;C¬ËùUm°E
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0Osy/lVbbBF&input=MTY)

```
;C¬ËùUm°E     :Implicit input of integer U
;C            :Lowercase alphabet
  ¬           :Split
   Ë          :Map each character at 0-based index E
    ù         :Left pad with spaces to length
     Um       :  Minimum of U and
       °E     :  E incremented
              :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 53 bytes

```forth
: f 1- 26. do dup i min spaces i 97 + emit cr loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdRCoAgEEDBq7z/MCiiqE4T2paQKWrn3@prGIm5nuaQH9UFoTP0Y4uLuCfhCf6mpM3u5cs80bAHX7GZK8bEig6Ivg)

Pretty standard answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes

```python
def f(n,a=0):
 b="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 for l in range(len(b)):print(" "*a,b[l]);a+=[0,1][l<n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg7EsIgEADQPqfYoQKliGMX5SQMxaKQoOuCiJ94efSVr6xtybzv/RwiRMkazaimAbwR6E//nJd0udKNc7nXR3u@3p/1KwaIuQJBYqjIc5AUWHqlplITNylAbFB7S04dcGvsqHfO0pFd7z8)

Answer (score 0):

## ><> (-v), 51+2 Bytes

```
'a'$1-0\   /' 'o1-81.
'z')?;}>::?/~$:@@:@)+{:oao1+:
```

**[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xz1RXcVQ1yBGQUFBX11BPd9Q18JQj0u9Sl3T3rrWzsrKXr9OxcrBwcpBU7vaKj8x31Db6v///7plCiYA)**

### equivalent pseudo code

```
char = 'a'
input = read_number
input -= 1
tabCount = 0

while true
    for i from 0 to tabCount
        print ' '
    if tabCount < input
        ++tabCount
    print char
    print '\n'
    ++char
    if char > 'z'
        exit
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>53</s></sub> 50 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input of expected type `Integer` in the domain of `[1,26]` from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=0To 25:[B1]=i:?Spc([Min(1:1)])Chr(97+i):Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brainbash](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Brainbash), 98 bytes

```
+[-[---<]>>-]<-~++++++++[>++++>+++>+<<<-]>>++>++>#-<<[>>>[-<<<<.>>>>>+<]>[-<+>]<<{->+<}<<-~.+~>.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYsxCoAwFEMP4/hJwcUp5CKfDu2ki4OOYq9ef4uBJDxC6lWOs5Z7790cDoBZQiaa/XKN1DRJxD5RC0iX5NFk0pDFPdiUyQeBbzxasqbE3Pu6fQ)

### Explanation

The code can be split into two parts:

```
+[-[---<]>>-]<-~++++++++[>++++>+++>+<<<-]>>++>++>#
-<<[>>>[-<<<<.>>>>>+<]>[-<+>]<<{->+<}<<-~.+~>.<]
```

Basically, generate the constants `97`, `32`, and `26`. Then, takes a number `N` as input. After input (`#`) the tape looks like:

```
[ ]   0      0     >97     0
[*]   0      32     26     10    >0
```

The second part executes `26` times, each time decrementing the input. Every time the input is decremented, the prefix length is incremented. After the input reaches zero, the prefix length remain constant. After each loop, the spaces, the letter, and a newline are printed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 48 bytes

```
f n{seq 1,26|min([n,_])<>chr 96+_1|print" "*_,_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P00hr7o4tVDBUMfIrCY3M08jOk8nPlbTxi45o0jB0kw73rCmoCgzr0RJQUkrXie@9n9uYmaeQjUXZ5qGiSZX7X8A)

Each output line has one leading space.

Explanation:

```
f n{
  seq 1,26|    /* push numbers 1..26 to the stream (inclusive) */
               /* for each number in the stream: */
  min([n,_])<> /*  push min(n, _1) */
  chr 96+_1|   /*  push string containing _1 as a letter */
               /* for each number _1 and letter _2 in the stream: */
  print" "*_,_ /*  print _1 spaces and _2 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 145 bytes

```
{n,_}=IO.gets("")|>Integer.parse;for x<-?a..?z,do: if x-97<n,do: IO.puts String.pad_leading(<<x>>,x-96),else: IO.puts String.pad_leading(<<x>>,n)
```

[Try online](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v@/Ok8nvtbW018vPbWkWENJSbPGzjOvJDU9tUivILGoONU6Lb9IocJG1z5RT8@@Sicl30ohM02hQtfS3CYPzANqLSgtKVYILinKzEsHakqJz0lNTAGyNWxsKuzsdIBqzTR1UnOKU4lQnKf5/7@RAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 67 bytes

```
<?for($l=a;$l!=aa;)echo str_pad($l++,min($argv[1],++$x)," ",0)."
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj4tv0hDJcc20VolR9E2MdFaMzU5I1@huKQoviAxBSijra2Tm5mnoZJYlF4WbRiro62tUqGpo6SgpGOgqafEpWT9//9/Q4N/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

Answer (score 0):

**VBA Excel, 51 bytes**

using Immediate Window and `[a1]` as input

```
for x=1to 26:?spc(iif(x<[a1],x,[a1]))chr(96+x):next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 107 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
I	&LCASE POS(R) LEN(1) . L
	OUTPUT =DUPL(' ',X) L
	R =R + 1
	X =LT(R,N) X + 1
	LT(R,26)	:S(I)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcq9CsIwFIbhObmKb7I5WISIdBAyiM0QOJyG/EBm52IH75/Y6vg@vJ/39trWW@9K4ILEWnRQJ34@skdcskkE9mIs4QLWaqllX@DmGtkMGMZGBye4hDOsVg2Oi0mjENpffnmdSN2zCaS9zL3b6Qs)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
27α‚A34SΛ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyPzcxkcNsxyNTYLPzf7/3xQA)

A golfed version of [the existing 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139650/52210) in the new 05AB1E version is **9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** as well:

```
Av<N‚ßyú,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fsczG71HDrMPzKw/v0vn/3xQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
27α        # Take the absolute difference of 27 with the (implicit) input
   ‚       # Pair it to the (implicit) input
    A      # Push the lowercase alphabet
     34S   # Push 34 as a list of digits: [3,4]
        Λ  # Use the Canvas builtin with these three as arguments:
           #  Direction [3,4], which translates to [↘,↓]
           #  Characters to draw: the lowercase alphabet
           #  Length of each part to draw: [input,|input-27|]
           # (after which the result is output immediately afterwards)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine for an in-depth explanation of how the canvas builtin works.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210)

```python
A          # Push the lowercase alphabet
 v         # Pop and loop over each of its characters `y`:
  <        #  Decrease the (implicit) input by 1
   N‚      #  Pair it with the 0-based loop index
     ß     #  Pop and push the minimum of this pair
      y    #  Push the current character
       ú   #  Pop both, and pad the character with leading spaces equal to the integer
        ,  #  Pop and print this string with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 9 bytes

```
ka¨2?‹∵Ip
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwia2HCqDI/4oC54oi1SXAiLCIiLCI1Il0=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda n:[f"{chr(65+i):>{min(i+1,n)}}"for i in range(26)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpNqTo5o0jDzFQ7U9PKrjo3M08jU9tQJ0@ztlYpLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDyEwz9n90QVFmXolGpqYCXDZNwxAow4VdBpcE2DAA)

Used python formatting to automatically put spaces in output i.e. `{'a':>5}` will give     `a`