# Semi-Diagonal Alphabet

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, alphabet

Given a letter of the English alphabet, your task is to build a semi-diagonal alphabet to the input.

### How to build a Semi-Diagonal alphabet?

**Brief Description**: 
First, you take the position of the letter in the alphabet, `P` (`P` is 1-indexed here). Then, you print each letter until the input (inclusive) on a line, preceded by `P-1` and repeat that letter `P` times, interleaving with spaces.

**Examples**:

- Given `F`, your program should output:

  ```
  A 
   B B 
    C C C 
     D D D D 
      E E E E E 
       F F F F F F
  ```
- Given `K`, your program should output:

  ```
  A
   B B 
    C C C 
     D D D D 
      E E E E E 
       F F F F F F 
        G G G G G G G 
         H H H H H H H H 
          I I I I I I I I I 
           J J J J J J J J J J 
            K K K K K K K K K K K
  ```
- Given `A`, your program should output:

  ```
  A
  ```

### Rules

- You may choose either lowercase or uppercase characters, but that should be consistent.
- You may have extraneous spaces as follows:

  - One consistent leading space (on each line).
  - A trailing or leading newline(s).
  - Trailing spaces.
- Input and output can be taken by any standard mean, and default loopholes apply.
- You are allowed to output a list of lines instead, as long as you also provide the [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) version.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

<sup>*Inspired by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125117/diagonal-alphabet)*.</sup>

Comment: Is output as list of strings ok?

Comment: It says under the rules that a list of lines is ok. I would assume this would mean yes @Adám

Comment: Ah, I can't read.

Comment: Why the downvote? What can i improve?

Comment: When you say "P is 1-indexed here", does here refer to the challenge or the example?

Comment: @pizzakingme The example, of course. `P` has no relevance overall

Comment: To rephrase, can we index from 0 and exclude the inputted character from the output?

Comment: @pizzakingme No, you may not.

Comment: I accidentlly got an interesting pattern while golfing my answer: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVGhupYLxMhUMDPlKsnMTVWohohHp@UX5SaWKMQoqCYrqGTGqiRaF5SWFMPFVaNTKwqKQDLFCiqJsdaZeclFCpm1CkZm//8DAA

Comment: Almost: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVGhupYLxMhUMDPhKsnMTVWohoirJEan5RflJpYoqBolK0Rn5iUXKWTGxloXlJYUK8ClIOLJCsaxMcVALbG1CkZm//8DAA

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda l:[' '*i+'%c '%(i+65)*-~i for i in range(ord(l)-64)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xck7DsIwDADQnVN4qWz3g4SgkajEyiUoQ2gJNQpOZXXpwtUDCwtvffO6TEn3OZz6HP3rNnqI3QUBS6mwGAALksq1XDZvgZAMBETBvD7ulGykyI078DX/lWvr4467DcwmuhD2ittnEqVAw2Qk/PVLzucP)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
lambda l:[' '*i+-~i*(chr(i+65)+' ')for i in range(ord(l)-64)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKlpdQV0rU1u3LlNLIzmjSCNT28xUUxsoqJmWX6SQqZCZp1CUmJeeqpFflKKRo6lrZqIZ@x9NysxUx9JQ04pLoaAoM69EQz0mT10vKz8zTyMNYqQmEMAkNf@7AQA) (link to pretty-print version)

Comment: I see absolutely no reason for a downvote. Can the @downvoter explain?

Comment: I'd imagine it's just a misclick, or perhaps someone not liking a lack of explanation (the latter is quite unlikely IMO)

Comment: I dislike Python and I can't implement with Python, so the answer is not useful for me? Just kidding, but the button tooltips probably do not fit the rules of this site

Comment: Is it just me or does it say Mr. Xcoder has 1 rep...?

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 59 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Rod. -2 bytes thanks to Felipe Nardi Batista.*

```python
i=1
exec"print' '*i+'%c '%(i+64)*i;i+=1;"*(ord(input())-64)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWkCu1IjVZqaAoM69EXUFdK1NbXTVZQV1VI1PbzERTK9M6U9vW0FpJSyO/KEUjM6@gtERDU1MXKPX/v7q3OgA)

Answer (score 8):

## C, 89 bytes

```
i,j;f(l){for(i=64;i++<l&&printf("%*c ",i-64,i);puts(""))for(j=i-65;j--;)printf("%c ",i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6TSNHszotv0gj09bMxDpTW9smR02toCgzryRNQ0lVK1lBSSdT18xEJ1PTuqC0pFhDSUlTE6Q8yxYobGqdpatrrQlXDlataV37H8hXyE3MzNPQ5KrmUgCCNA11N3VNaxjbG4ntCGLX/gcA)

Answer (score 7):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```powershell
65..$args[0]|%{" "*$i+++"$([char]$_) "*$i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/38xUT08lsSi9ONogtka1WklBSUslU1tbW0lFIzo5I7EoViVeEyxW@///f6iQupu6JgA)

Takes input as a literal char, then loops up through the capitals to that point, each iteration prepending the appropriate number of spaces and then the char\space hybrid.

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to TessellatingHeckler.*

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Indeed. I've been golfing that to `"$args"` so much, which wouldn't work here, I forgot about the `[0]` method. Haha.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 85 bytes

Works in lower case for both input and output. Outputs a leading space and a trailing space on each line.

```js
f=(c,k=10,C=k.toString(36),r=s=>`${s} `.repeat(k-9))=>r``+r(C)+(C==c?'':`
`+f(c,k+1))
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(c,k=10,C=k.toString(36),r=s=>`${s} `.repeat(k-9))=>r``+r(C)+(C==c?'':`
`+f(c,k+1))

O.innerText = f('m')
```

```html
<pre id=O>
```

Comment: `\`${s} \`` can be replaced by `(s+"")` for one byte saving

Comment: @Luke I need this space. It can be replaced by `(s+" ")`, but that's just as long.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

Prompts for scalar character. Prints list of lines.

```apl
(∊⍴∘'',' ',¨⍨⊢⍴⊃∘⎕A)¨⍳⎕A⍳⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9fXfyobcKjvql@wQqPetcoPOpuUTCzsgIKBLvqhTr7uqgn5Vco5Ocp6KbZ5uepP@paXKyXmpeYlJMa7OgTAlb@qGtRsR5Qg3OkenFiTol6LdAcrkcd7cGpuZkumYnp@XmJOf81HnV0Perd8qhjhrq6jrqCus6hFY96VwC1ggS7moHiQBMcNUGim0EsCPUfaAy6UY7FyZmZjkUlXI/aJpJnKsjE/wpggGwwl7qbOhc2YW/swo7YhOGuw24YQtobvzTQcAA) (has ASCII art version at one additional byte)

`⎕` prompt for input

`⎕A⍳` find **ɩ**ndex in **A**lphabet

`⍳` first that many **ɩ**ntegers

`(`…`)¨` apply the following tacit function to each :

`⊃∘⎕A` pick the argument'th letter letter from the **A**lphabet

`⊢⍴` cyclically reshape it to the argument length

`' ',¨⍨` append a space to each

`⍴∘'',` prepend a string of argument length (padded with spaces)

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

---

The ASCII art version just has a `↑` on the very left; mix list of strings into table of characters.

Answer (score 4):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 31 bytes

**30 bytes code + 1 for `-l`.**

```perl
print$"x$-,"$_ "x++$-for A..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvREWpQkVXR0klXkGpQltbRTctv0jBUU/Pxu7/f@9/@QUlmfl5xf91cwA)

Comment: You can cut this down by using `say` instead of the `-l` flag: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFqUJFV0dJJV5BqUJbW0U3Lb9IwVFPz8bu/3/vf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Xcali I'm torn on `-E`/`-M5.01`, I've used `say` considerably in the past, and would probably abuse the fact that `say` is an alternative to `print` in a restricted source challenge or similar perhaps, but for the sake of -3, I'll keep as-is for now. See [this meta post for a fair argument](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7539/9365). Appreciate the input though!

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 38 bytes

```apl
{↑{(y/' '),(2×y←⎕A⍳⍵)⍴⍵,' '}¨⎕A↑⍨⎕A⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR20TqzUq9dUV1DV1NIwOT68ECj7qm@r4qHfzo96tmo96twApHaB07aEVYPG2iY96VyBU1ALNUTi0Qt3RzTtKHQA)

**How?**

`⎕A↑⍨` - take the alphabet until

`⎕A⍳⍵` - the input character

`¨` - for each char

`⍵,' '` - take the char and a space

`(...)⍴` - reshape to

`2×y←⎕A⍳⍵` - twice the index of the char in the alphabet

`(y/' ')` - and prepend index-of-char spaces

`↑` - then flatten

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
A¹¡н«ðâƶāú
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f8wNWFiMWX//0HCucKh0L3Cq8Oww6LGtsSBw7r//2Y)

-2 thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan).

Append `»` to make it print in separate lines.

Comment: You could omit the `<` as one consistent leading space is okay.

Comment: `A¹¡н«ðâƶāú` should work for 10 bytes

Comment: @Adnan I think that `¹¡` will make it not work...oh so that's why there's a `«` in there. :p

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>28, 26, 25</s>, 23 bytes ([Competing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/31716))

```
¬A[/a
lDÓ./& ò
ò-Ûä$Û>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v92///CrEFbLxJhCmxEw5MuLyYgw7IKw7Itw5vDpCTDmz7///9G)

Note that although I have been planning on adding [certain features](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/commit/5de2c51e581014a2693a8c6d68cdfb3378343510) for a long time, this challenge was what convinced me to finally do it.

The output contains one leading space on each line and one trailing newline.

Hexdump:

```
00000000: ac41 5b2f 1261 0a6c 44d3 2e2f 2620 f20a  .A[/.a.lD../& ..
00000010: f22d dbe4 24db 3e                        .-..$.>
```

Explanation:

```
¬A[         " Insert 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ['
   /        " Search for...
    <C-r>a  "   The input
l           " Move one character to the right
 D          " And delete every character after the cursor
  Ó         " Search for...
   .        "   Any character
    /       " And replace it with...
     & ò    "   That character followed by a space and a newline
ò           " Recursively...
 -          "   Move to the beginning of the next line up
  Ûä$       "   Make *line number* copies of the current line
     Û>     "   And indent this line by *line number* spaces
```

Comment: This is competing. You may remove the title remark.

Comment: It's useful for those who weren't aware of the new meta, such as myself

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

```apl
{↑{(≠\⍵<⍳3×⍵)\⍵⊃⎕A}¨⍳⎕A⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/@lHbxGqNR50LYh71brV51LvZ@PB0IEsTxH3U1fyob6pj7aEVQHEQC0T1bq0lT5e6mzoA)

#### Explanation

```apl
                      ⍳⎕A⍳⍵  generate indexes up to position of right arg ⍵
{                   }¨       on each index apply function
   (≠\⍵<⍳3×⍵)                generate boolean mask for expansion (each line has a length 3 times its index ⍵, starting with ⍵ blanks and then alternating letter blank)
             \⍵⊃⎕A          expand character in position ⍵
 ↑                            mix result into text matrix
```

Comment: Goodness... 4 APL-er solving the same problem at the same time! :) I think in codegolf you're allowed to remove the outer `{}`, replace `⍵` with `⎕`, and claim it's a "complete program" rather than a function. That would make your solution the best (so far).

Comment: Must be a good sign :) Thanks for the suggestion. I've seen it done but wasn't sure where to draw the line. I guess that I can save 3 bytes if I remove curlies and mix.

Answer (score 3):

## R,  <strike>94</strike> 88  bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```
function(x,l=LETTERS)for(i in 1:match(x,l))cat(rep(' ',i-1),rep(paste(l[i],' '),i),'\n')}
```

Ungolfed:

```
f=function(x,l=letters){
  for(i in 1:which(l==x)){
    A=paste(l[i],' ')
    cat(rep(' ',i-1),rep(A,i),'\n')
  }
}
```

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcmxDkAwEIDhV7lYepecoauwSGwmbBiaRuMSSqoSb1@M//eH5KDMIbnb2yiHx4e3qm2Goel6ckdAAfGgi91Eu/6TyJqIYTlRgWLJNfEfp7nigtsoM39OLMRq8oqSw6zOKL0 "R – Try It Online") : returning an anonymous function is fine, you can get rid of the braces since `f` is a one-liner, and using `match` instead of `which` saves a byte.

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP0@jQifH1sc1JMQ1KFgzLb9II1MhM0/B0Co3sSQ5AySpqZmcWKJRlFqgkayhpKSTE50Zq6mTapupqaPEpaT5P01DyRVIAQA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdAqN7EkOUOjODkxT0NHSUlTJ8dG18c1JMQ1KFhTMzmxRKMotUAjWUNJSScnOjNWUyfVNlNTRykmT0nzv/d/AA) taking input from stdin.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>52</s> 44 bytes

```
f k=[[" ",s:" "]>>=(['A'..s]>>)|s<-['A'..k]]
```

Returns a list of lines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h2zY6WklBSafYCkjG2tnZakSrO6rr6RUD2Zo1xTa6EG52bOz/3MTMPAVbhdzEAt94hYLSkuCSIp88BRWFNAV1V/X/AA)

```
f k=                  -- main function is f, input parameter k
  [   |s<-['A'..k]]   -- for each s from ['A'..k]
     >>=              -- map (and collect the results in a single string) the function: 
         (['A'..s]>>) --  replace each element in ['A'..s] with
    [  ,  ]           --  over the list, containing
     " "              --   a single space to get the indent
        s:" "         --   s followed by space to get the letter sequence
```

Edit: @jferard: saved three bytes. Thanks!

Comment: 49 bytes:`f k=[tail$[" ",s:" "]>>=(['A'..s]>>)|s<-['A'..k]]`

Comment: @jferard: Thanks a lot. Rereading the challenge I noticed that a leading space per line is allowed, so we don't need the `tail$`.

Answer (score 3):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
z+ḣ∞øzRNC1…'A
```

Takes a character in single quotes as command line argument, prints result to STDOUT.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v0r74Y7FjzrmHd5RFeTnbPioYZm64////9Xd1AE)

### Explanation

I'm exploiting the way Husk prints lists of lists of strings: join inner lists with spaces and outer lists with newlines.

```
z+ḣ∞øzRNC1…'A  Implicit input, say 'C'
          …'A  Range from A: "ABC"
        C1     Cut into strings of length 1: ["A","B","C"]
     z N       Zip with positive integers
      R        using repetition: x = [["A"],["B","B"],["C","C","C"]]
   ∞ø          The empty string repeated infinitely: ["","","",...
  ḣ            Prefixes: [[],[""],["",""],["","",""],...
z+             Zip with x using concatenation: [["A"],["","B","B"],["","","C","C","C"]]
               Implicitly join each inner list with spaces, join the resulting strings with newlines and print.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ethproductions/japt/) `-R`, <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

Outputs an array, includes a leading newline and a leading & trailing space on each line.

```
IòUc ÏçSiXd¹iYç
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=SfJVYyDP51NpWGS5aVnn&input=IksiCi1S)

- 1 byte saved with help from [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver) and a further 6 thanks to him pointing out a better way to generate the initial array.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Adnan*

```
A¹¡н«ƶ€S»¶¡āú»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/8wNWFiMWX//0HCucKh0L3Cq8a24oKsU8K7wrbCocSBw7r//2Y)
or the [Ascii art version](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f8wNWFiMWX//0HCucKh0L3Cq8a24oKsU8K7wrbCocSBw7rCu///Zg)

**Explanation**

```
A                # push lowercase alphabet
 ¹¡              # split at input
   н             # get the first part
    «            # append the input
     ƶ           # repeat each a number of times corresponding to its 1-based index
      €S         # split each to a list of chars
        »        # join on spaces and newlines
         ¶¡      # split on newlines
           āú    # prepend spaces to each corresponding to its 1-based index
             »   # join on newlines
```

Comment: It looks like [we handled it a bit differently](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140213/41024) :D

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: We did it quite similarly, but your very nice idea to append a space before lifting, removing the need for the join made yours shorter. I hadn't read that leading/trailing spaces nor output as list was okay, so that'll hopefully teach me to read the whole challenge before implementing :P

Comment: tl;dr: vectorization :p

Comment: `A¹¡н«` instead of `ADIk>£` should work

Comment: @Adnan: Thanks! I did have `A¹¡н` but didn't consider `«` to get the last letter so it wasn't good enough :P

Comment: You might have the links to the TIO and ASCII art version swapped

Comment: @Graviton: Indeed I do. Meaning since I switched them to this order, I actually had them correct the first time and then messed it up. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES8), 92 bytes

```js
c=>(g=n=>n>9?[...g(n-1),`${n.toString(36)} `.repeat(n-=9).padStart(n*3)]:[])(parseInt(c,36))
```

Uses lowercase letters. Lines have one leading and one trailing space. Returns an array of lines.

### Test Snippet

```js
let f=

c=>(g=n=>n>9?[...g(n-1),`${n.toString(36)} `.repeat(n-=9).padStart(n*3)]:[])(parseInt(c,36))

;O.innerText=f("k").join`\n`
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
⍕⍪⊢∘⊂\2,.↑⍉⍴⍨⌸⎕a↑⍨⎕a⍳⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZv6jtgmGXI862tP@P@qd@qh31aOuRY86Zjzqaoox0tF71DbxUW/no94tj3pXPOrZAdSQCBZaAWb1bn7UO@8/UO//NC5vAA)

Uses `⎕io←1`. Prints a leading space, which is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## QBasic, <s>79</s> <s>74</s> 72 bytes

*Thanks to Taylor Scott for [byte savings](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45347921#45347921) (twice!)*

```
FOR i=1TO ASC(INPUT$(1))-64
?TAB(i)
FOR j=1TO i
?CHR$(64+i)" ";
NEXT j,i
```

Uses uppercase. The input is by keypress and is not echoed to the screen.

#### Explanation

We loop `i` from `1` up to the limiting letter's position in the alphabet (1-based). For each `i`, we move to column `i` of the screen using `TAB`; then, `i` times, we print the `i`th letter of the alphabet followed by a space.

Comment: As it turns out you can use the `INPUT$(1)` command as a direct replacement for the variable `z$` for a delta of -2 bytes

Comment: @TaylorScott Good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
Ｆ⁺⌕αθ¹«Ｐ×⁺§αι ⁺ι¹↘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmWPGnc96pl6buO5HYd2Hlr9fs@Gw9OBQoeWA0V2KgBZ53Ye2vmobcb//24A)

Comment: Nah, you can't let 05AB1E beat Charcoal... :P

Comment: @totallyhuman [the revenge :p](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140213/41024)

Comment: Sadly arbitrary leading whitespace isn't allowed otherwise `Ｅ…·?θ⁺× κ⪫× κι` would do the job in 14 bytes.

Comment: @Neil One leading whitespace is allowed, but I'm not sure how `?` got in there. It should be `A` instead I think. Oh wait, ohhhhh I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 17 bytes

```
.e+*kd*+bdhk<GhxG
```

**[Try it here (pretty print version).](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.e%2B%2akd%2a%2Bbdhk%3CGhxG&input=%22r%22&debug=0)**

---

## How does this work?

- `hxG` - Takes the index of the input in the lowercase alphabet.
- `<G` - Trims every character after the input from the alphabet.
- `.e` - Enumerated Map. Maps over the trimmed alphabet with the indexes as `k` and the letters as `b`.
- `*kd` - Append `k` spaces.
- `+bd` - `b` + a space (the current letter + space).
- `*...hk` - Repeat `k+1` times.
- `+(...)(...)` - Concatenate.

Comment: One of my favorite things about Pyth is writing an answer and finding that someone wrote the same answer, character for character. It hits that Python "there is a best answer" spot perfectly!

Comment: @pizzakingme Yeah, I wonder if I can do better

Comment: the space addition feels wrong, I think better is possible

Comment: @pizzakingme I could get `.e+*kdjd*bhk<GhxG` as 17 bytes as well

Comment: 16 bytes: `.e+*kd*+bdhkhcGQ`

Comment: Oh actually that doesn't include Q

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 65 bytes

```
a#a-# 7-,-~vc<!?>[$_]:$_|&,(.#a-!?.>[# M]1+>[.M# M]:$_!@|v#
&@R);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/UTlRV1nBXFdHt64s2UbR3i5aJT7WSiW@Rk1HQw8op2ivZxetrOAba6htF63nC2IBZRUdasqUudQcgjSt////XwUA)

Lowercase.

Contains 1 trailing space on each line, and a trailing newline at the end of output.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ZZ,Wm{ē@Ο}¹¾
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=WlolMkNXbSU3QiV1MDExM0AldTAzOUYlN0QlQjklQkU_,inputs=RiUwQSUyMEElMkMldTAzOUQlN0I_)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 70 bytes

```
(T=Table)[""<>{" "~T~i,T[Alphabet[][[i]]<>" ",i]},{i,LetterNumber@#}]&
```

lowercase

outputs a list

*thanx @ngenisis for corrections*

For [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) version place `Column@` at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>102</s> 94 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```js
f=
a=>[...Array(parseInt(a,36)-9)].map((a,b)=>''.padEnd(b).padEnd(b*3+1,(b+10).toString(36)+' '))

console.log(f('k').join`\n`)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 103 bytes

```cs
n=>{var i='`';var l="";for(;i<n;l+='\n'){l+="".PadLeft(i++-96);for(int s=96;s++<i;)l+=i+" ";}return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xagMxEETr01csaiSh2KXB7MmNwZUDCSnSpIiQ5cuCIoFWZ0iO@/bL2ZnqwTyGCbwJpcZlZMoDvP1wi98oREieGV7FJGANN98owK3QBZ49ZW3gv7jnNObQhy9fn7jVdeQAAzhYsjtMN1@BnPpUeKfkpMRrqRqpz5isUx9ZmWkFKbcv/nKO16bJ2s1@Zx4e5Qbs9jtka3tCs5pkJUica2xjzZBwXlB0x5K5pLh9r9TimXLUg1a/yhgUs@i6x1MxL38)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 51 bytes

```
^.
$&$&
}T`L`_L`^.
.
$.`$* $&$.`$* ¶
+`(\w) \B
$&$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/To9LRU1Fjas2JMEnId4nAcgHiuglqGgpAMXB9KFtXNoJGjHlmgoxTiDFhv//uwEA) Explanation:

```
^.
$&$&
```

Duplicate the (first) letter.

```
}T`L`_L`^.
```

Rotate it back 1 in the alphabet, or delete it if it's a duplicate `A`. Keep duplicating and rotating until we duplicate `A`, at which point the deletion undoes the duplication and the loop completes.

```
.
$.`$* $&$.`$* ¶
```

Replace each letter with a line with the letter padded on both sides.

```
+`(\w) \B
$&$1
```

Insert duplicate letters between all pairs of padding spaces to the right of existing letters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 bytes

```hs
x!'@'=x
x!e=([e]:[' ':r++' ':[last r]|r<-x])!pred e
([]!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0JR3UHdtoKrQjHVViM6NdYqWl1B3apIWxtEReckFpcoFMXWFNnoVsRqKhYUpaYopP7PTczMsy0oLQkuKVIpzcvJzEstVomOVVQPVP8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｆ…·AＳ«Ｐ⪫Ｅ…@ιι ↘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsIwEADP@oqQ0y7YD@hFQYQKvdQXhBDThbAJaRIP4tu3AXuYyzBjF5NtNEHkHbOCkW2oKzU3G/YO9E2f1MipllfJxB4QUX2Ph6mGQqmbAs9IDJNJsB/XfhD@0UojXnoem4PzPX54Jr@Urn4iDxmaDGvYAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 …·AＳ           Inclusive character range from A to the input
Ｆ    «          Loop over each character
         …@ι    Exclusive range from @ to the current character
        Ｅ   ι   Replace each element with the current character
       ⪫        Join with spaces
      Ｐ         Print without moving the cursor.
              ↘ Move the cursor down and right.
```

If extra padding was legal, this would work for 14 bytes:

```
Ｅ…·?θ⁺× κ⪫× κι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDMy85p7Q4syw1KDEvPVVDyV5JR6FQU0chACiqEZKZm1qsoaQAFMsGinnlZ@ahi2VqAoH1//9u/3XL/usW5wAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 72 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To Asc([A1])-64:[B1]=i:?Space(i-1)[REPT(CHAR(B1+64)&" ",B1)]:Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Very naïve approach.

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 100 bytes

```
time {puts [format %[incr i]s \ ][string repe [format %c\  [expr $i+64]] $i]} [expr [scan $c %c]-64]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYrBCsJADAV/5R3qSbwVP6ZpDiWmJWDXJUlBEL993YPQ08DMpDzbphmIfFiBtLRd8alHV7S@fF8SF7IiDuPADKZIt7LBteq5yAyQvqtjsOt9ZO7k719RyFIwSN/41mNr0w8)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 106 bytes

```
set i 0;while \$i<[scan $c %c]-64 {puts [format %$i.s \ ][string repe [format %2c [expr $i+65]] [incr i]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCsJADAXQq/zFdCWKiHajJ3GaRYmxBuo4JJEK4tlHd67fC57bJOHwuGgBN5eAYntcbjoLhqSn7DwWJEbHtO73eNfn7@frw@5joEu6cQyg7GFaJphU@euOkeVVDUlX/YEIWQsblOjT2vkL)

---

Below approahes do not have a leading space

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 107 bytes

```
set i 0;while \$i<[scan $c %c]-64 {puts [format %$i.s \ ][string repe [format %c [expr $i+65]]\  [incr i]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcoxDsIwDAXQq/whnRCIAbrASXA8VMYUSyVEsRFIiLMHNub3QpY@azg8zlYg3TVg2B6eV1sUOdmRXKaCJBiE1@MO7/r4fbrc220KDMk2jgwmj2ZlRtOqfxWQvmpDstW4Z84AWZEGY/70fvoC)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 109 bytes

```
set i 0;time {puts [format %$i.s \ ][string repe [format %c [expr $i+65]]\  [incr i]]} [expr [scan $c %c]-64]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcoxCgJBDAXQq/xirESx0G2sPUU2xRLjEnDHIYkgiGcftxCs30u591kzEHm1CumhCcPhnLYo3u25Et0evkyJTbF9YARTpFud4dr0rwLSV3MU2w4n5hEgq@Iw5s@PKGSqKLJm3g1H7v3yBQ)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 111 bytes

```
set i 0;time {puts [string repe \  $i][string repe [format %c [expr $i+65]]\  [incr i]]} [expr [scan $c %c]-64]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcoxCgJBDEbhq/zFWolgodtYe4qYYonZJeCOQxJBEM8@TmGz7XtfyqMtmoHIuxVIC00Yjpe0VfGpr74o0q0scK2KGzAYbxLNT1@nxE5A@q7ewX48M3dKVsRhzN//opCpYJCO@TCeuLXrDw)

Comment: Failed outgolf on https://tio.run/##PYyxCoQwEER7v2IKLa9RsfEzrsxtETZRFjQnyQqC@O25iHDdzBveKC959pqQ1EkA5@QVFudV3UEw9JXK6nE@vLZm@sbVKpqWYSRwhBCN214u/tPDHTr6pKLQBXPrDsYfWyyFbUDNaJheQ0@U8/sH

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 164 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#define f for(int i=0;i<o-'`';i++)
using namespace std;int main(){char c;cin>>c;for(char o='a';o<=c;o++){f cout<<' ';f cout<<o<<' ';cout<<'\n';}}
```

My first attempt after a long time lurking!

Ungolfed code below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define f for (auto i = 0; i < output - '`'; i++)

int main()
{
  char input;

  cin >> input;

  for (char output = 'a'; output <= input; output++)
  {
    f cout << ' ';

    f cout << output << ' ';

    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLDoMwDET3nMISi4AQUvcOnKSLRiahroqNSLJCnD0t/exm5o0erWs/E5VSs9AzT96yxrR5t4xVPfnA4iFA0K1hScDDBdlqb24GuevaKkeWGcQtPq6OPMQ04XlcHEvT7nR3GxASyzgSnpbPooNxBtUOhPq27AFIc7LWgMF/1m/9gasYPI5SHi8)

Comment: I know there has to be a bunch of golfing things to do, but so far, that's the smallest I've gotten.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 111 bytes

```
>+[+[<]>>+<+],>>++++++++++>++++[>++++++++<-]----[<<<->>>----]<<<-[<[-<+>>>>>.<<<<]+<[->+>>.>>.<<<<<]>>>.+>.<<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCoBQCAUPZHqCx7tBJxAXFQQRtAg6v2nEn43zZuF6L8e1P9uZSXFxBCmQmOoMPvURoKGFA1CS7dHucIWwsdoIqcAK9od@TpMeGpnzCw)

Surprising how the Turing Tarpit itself can out-golf some other languages.

#### The breakdown:

`Section A`

```
>+[+[<]>>+<+]                                                       create character 'A'
             ,                                                      take input
              >>++++++++++                                          create '\n' character
                          >++++[>++++++++<-]                        create ' ' character
                                            ----[<<<->>>----]<<<-   map input to (1->26)
```

`Section B`

```
[<[-<+>>>>>.<<<<]+                                 print N spaces, then increment N
                  <[->+>>.>>.<<<<<]                print (N-1) of the Nth letter and spaces
                                   >>>.+>.<<-]     print additional letter, and newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 85 Bytes

```
i1-&0\1o*84\      \o*84o:$\
@)?;&>:> :?/~1+:88*+$:@>:?/~ao&:
     /-/          /$1- /
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9NQV80gxjBfy8IkRgEMYkDsfCuVGC4HTXtrNTsrOwUre/06Q20rCwstbRUrBzsQNzFfzYoLrF5fV18BDvRVDHUV9P//dwMA)

Comment: This is almost a four-finned fish... coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 81 bytes

```java
c->{String s="";for(int d=64;d++<c;)System.out.printf((s=" "+s+"%1$c ")+"%n",d);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xa8MwEIX3/IpDpETCiaBQuigOhECW0ilj6aCepFSuLRnpFCjBv90VSad2esd3H4/X6YvexNGGznzNY/noPQL2Omd41T7AdQHwSzNpqnGJ3sBQf/xEyYfz2zvodM7ipgJ0tU8W8r10JSD5GOQhhlwGm7aHT500kk07cO2Mm931XgG5ZUy5mLgPBKZ9flKmabaoxOk7kx1kLCTHapLjvLrAmtywh8clAhP1CGxthJpmdVvgpEa0I/HVcSX@opf/aH9H02KafwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 179 bytes

```
({}[((((()()()()){}){}){}){}]){((({}[()])())){({}<(({})<>((((()()()()){}){}){}){
})((((()()()()){}){}){})<>>[()])}{}{({}[()])<>((((()()()()){}){}){})<>}{}<>{}(((
)()()()()){})<>}<>
```

This is 178 bytes of code, and `+1` for the `-c` flag.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6NloDBDQhULO6Fo5iNauBEiAFmrEgKSC3utYGJKJpY4dLkyZ2CRs7O7AxtdW11TAjcRliYwdUZWNXXYuQhEgDJWzs/v/3@q@bDAA)

(Semi-)Readable version:

```
({}[((((()()()()){}){}){}){}])

{

    ((({}[()])()))

    {
        ({}<

            (({})<>((((()()()()){}){}){}){})
            ((((()()()()){}){}){})<>

        >[()])
    }{}

    {
        ({}[()])
        <>
        ((((()()()()){}){}){})
        <>
    }{}

    <>{}

    ((()()()()()){})

    <>

}
```

Fun fact: This will work with arbitrary characters above `Z`! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYwxDoAwCEWvU4begHAR06GamBiNg@sPXh3BRl0ssMD7vPGoy57nra5mCTqkKGpN0HcKwUEEqATyFcpxIZbeE/0DFrk1CsWj7ElYPMUC/WDDDljMTsvTBQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>93</s> 90 bytes

```bash
for c in {A..Z}
{
printf "%$[i++*3+2]s\n" "$(echo `yes $c|head -$i`)"
[ $c = $1 ]&&break
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCFZITNPodpRTy@qlquaq6AoM68kTUFJVSU6U1tby1jbKLY4Jk9JQUlFIzU5I18hoTK1WEEluSYjNTFFQVclM0FTiSsaKKBgq6BiqBCrppZUlJqYzVX7//9/dwA)

Takes input as, and outputs as, uppercase letters.

Still getting the hang of golfing in Bash, so I'm open to tips.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>115</strike> 109 Bytes

```
f(a,n,k,s,i){if(k){for(;i<s;i++)printf(" ");for(i=0;i<s+1;i++)printf("%c ",a);puts();f(++a,++n,--k,++s,0);}}
```

### Usage

```
f(65,5,5,0,0)
```

Where the two 5's are the given K value, the rest are constants used later for recursive calls.

### Ungolfed

```
f(a,n,k,s,i){
    if(k){
        for (; i<s; i++) printf(" ");
        for (i=0; i<s+1; i++) printf("%c ",a);
        puts();
        f(++a,++n,--k,++s,0);
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 77 bytes

```c
i,j;f(c){for(j=64;i||j++<c&&printf("\n%*c ",i=j-64,j);--i&&printf("%c ",j));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6TSNZszotv0gjy9bMxDqzpiZLW9smWU2toCgzryRNQykmT1UrWUFJJ9M2S9fMRCdL01pXNxMhrQqSy9LUtK79DxRQyE3MzNMoy89M0eSq5lIAgjQNdTd1TWsY2xvErv0PAA)

<strike>Contains unsequenced access to possibly incremented `j`, so very likely to break with a different compiler :)</strike>

fixed with identical byte count

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 31 bytes

```
/A''*?h~w0O~
\I"AxrS&..r!y"kx@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fUV1dyz6jrtzAv44rxlPJsaIoWE1Pr0ixUim7wkH//38XAA)

#### Explanation

Linearized and with relevant spaces included, the program is as follows:

```
I'A*rh&w.O!" x A"'x?S~.0r~yk@

I                                   take input
 'A*                                append the letter A
    r                               expand to range (e.g., if input was D, string is now DCBA)
     h&w                            split string into characters, and repeat the main loop that number of times
        .O                          output copy of top string on stack with newline
          !                         move top string (last printed row) to tape
           " x A"                   push " x A"
                 'x S               replace the occurrence of "x" with
                   ?                  the string on the tape
                     ~              swap to get next letter
                      .             copy this letter
                       0r           get entire range from that letter down to "0"
                         ~          swap again to put letter on top of stack
                          y         replace all characters in this range (effectively, all non-space characters) with the next letter
                           k        repeat (end of main loop)
                            @       exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <del>18</del> 17 bytes

*-1 thanks to @TheIOSCoder because you are apparently allowed to surround the input in quotes*

```
j.b+*dYjd*NhYGhxG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0svSVsrJTIrRcsvI9I9o8K96v9/AA)

**Explanation**

```
j.b+*dYjd*NhYGhxG    accepts a token as input, must be lowercase and in quotes

j                    joins on new line
 .b   Y   N Y        maps A (lambdas NY) over B and C in parallel
   +                 joins two strings on same line
    *    *           repeats A B times
     d  d            " " or space
       j             joins B on A
           h  h      A + 1
             G  G    lowercase alphabet
               x     returns position of B in A
                     implicit input
```

Comment: You can use the input with quotes around to save 1 byte through implicit input (`Q`) - [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0svSVsrJTIrRcsvI9I9o8L9/3@lVCUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 28 bytes

```
{B-Oa64"P+*' '~}J' '*}C+64}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/2knXP9HMRClAW0tdQb2u1gtIatU6a5uZ1Cr9/68epQ4A)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 69+1 bytes

```php
A<?for($c=A;$c<$argn;)echo($p=str_pad)($p("
",++$i+1),$i*3,++$c." ");
```

Run as pipe with `-nF` or try it online.

---

The `Z` case cost 4 bytes. `for($c=A;$c<=$argn;)echo($p=str_pad)($p("
",++$i),$i*3,$c++." ");` (with `-nR`) works for `A` to `Y`.

Printing a list of underscore-separated lines would save two bytes, but that´d feel like cheating.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 35 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c${,/(x#32),(x+1)#,65+x,-33}'!-64+
```

Returns list of strings. prepend `` `0: `` to write to stdout instead.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/PyFZpVpHX6NC2dhIU0ejQttQU1nHzFS7QkfX2LhWXVHXzERbyVvp/38A)

**Example:**

```
`c${,/(x#32),(x+1)#,65+x,-33}'!-64+"F"
("A "
 " B B "
 "  C C C "
 "   D D D D "
 "    E E E E E "
 "     F F F F F F ")
```

**Explanation:**

Struggled to golf this down any further... K is interpretted right-to-left:

```
`c${,/(x#32),(x+1)#,65+x,-33}'!-64+ / the solution
                               -64+ / subtract 64 from input, "F"=>6 (implicit ascii)
                              !     / til, !6 => 0 1 2 3 4 5
   {                        }'      / lambda function with each input
                         -33        / negative 33
                       x,           / x concatenated, e.g. 0 -33
                    65+             / add 65, 0 -33 => 65 32 (aka "A ")
                   ,                / enlist, wraps "A " into a list ("A ")
             (x+1)#                 / take (#) x+1 instances of this list
            ,                       / concatenate with
      (x#32)                        / x instances of the number 32 (aka " ")
    ,/                              / raze, flattens this list down
`c$                                 / cast to characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 76 bytes

```c
i,j;f(c){for(i=0;i++<c-64;puts(""))for(j=0;j<i;)printf("%*c",j++?2:i,i+64);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6TSNZszotv0gj09bAOlNb2yZZ18zEuqC0pFhDSUlTEySTBZTJssm01iwoyswrSdNQUtVKVtLJ0ta2N7LK1MnUNjPRtK79D5RSyE3MzNPQ5Krm4kzTUHdT17QGM7xhDEcQo/Y/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 62 Bytes

Assumes input as a string (e.g., 'A'). Wasn't clear from the rules whether this was allowed. Will update if not.

*Lots* of room for improvement, I'm sure.

```
->n{a=[*'A'..n];a.map{|x|' '*a.index(x)+(x+' ')*-~a.index(x)}}
```

Comment: BTW This is definitely a valid way to take input. +1

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>78</s></sub> 71 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To[Code(A1)-64]:?:?Spc(i-1);:For j=1To i:?Chr(i+64)" ";:Next j,i
```

-1 Byte for switching to leading newline over trailing, and condensing `Next` statements

-6 bytes for using `Spc()` over `String()`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
FxzIxLEaPsXi.YxX++iJs
```

Uses lowercase and takes input from the command line. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fraLKs8LHNTGgOCJTL7IiQls706v4////aQA)

#### Explanation

Implicit: `a` is 1st cmdline arg; `z` is lowercase alphabet; `i` is `0`; `s` is space.

```
Fxz                      For each letter x in lowercase alphabet:
   IxLEa                  If x is less than or equal to a:
        P                  Print
         sXi               i spaces
            .Y             to which concatenate (the Y enforces precedence)
              xX++i        x repeated i times, after incrementing i
                   Js      joined on spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 115 bytes

```
	U =&UCASE
	U INPUT @L
N	U POS(X) LEN(1) . R
	OUTPUT =DUPL(' ',X) DUPL(R ' ',X + 1)
	X =LT(X,L - 1) X + 1	:S(N)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq7CsMwEARr6Su2ik/ECRhSBQR5WEXgOAtLB6pdh7jI/6Mo6mZ29vvZt/19qdUo/EGf9xRsw5dEzbixlSZxSVQcOAhNDmes1iya/wc/a2QaMIytd17RDUdMzpoCz5nKyDg1R5/NNZE4G2Su9fED)

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 133 bytes

```swift
func f(c:String){for i in 9..<Int(c,radix:36)!{var s=""
for _ in 9..<i{s+=" "}
for _ in 9...i{s+=String(i+1,radix:36)+" "}
print(s)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/rTQvWSFNI9kquKQoMy9dszotv0ghUyEzT8FST8/GM69EI1mnKDEls8LK2ExTsbossUih2FZJiQukLB6mLLO6WNtWSUGpFkVYDywMMVcjU9sQYY42WG0BUKJEo1iztvY/yAFKbkqa/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 48 bytes

It should work the same in more recent versions of Julia as well.

```julia
x->[" "^i*"$c "^i for (i,c) in enumerate('A':x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8n2ablJqemfe/QtcuWklBKS5TS0klGUQrpOUXKWhk6iRrKmTmKaTmleamFiWWpGqoO6pbVWjG/k/NS@FKySwuyEms1EjTUHdT19TkKijKzCvJydPQRJbxBsr8BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 40 bytes

```julia
c->[" "^i*"$('A'+i) "^-~i for i=0:c-'A']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9Z1y5aSUEpLlNLSUVD3VFdO1MTyNOty1RIyy9SyLQ1sErWBQrH/s9NLNAoKMrMK8nJ01FI01B3UdfU5OJCF/UAiv4HAA)

Returns an array of strings containing the output. (Pretty printed on TIO using just `map (println, f(c))`.)

`^` applied to strings repeats the string that many times. `$()` executes its content and pastes the result into the string (here, the correct letter for the line). Finally, the space repetition and the letter repetition are concatenated with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque - 39 bytes

```
-]'Ajr@id?i?*m{' []}zim{p^' j?*j_+}unsh
```

This is not fully golfed yet and (trivially at least the `sh` can be replaced with `Q`) but it's a first start. `m{}un` can probably be replaced by a version of map that unlines and `zim[` is a good candidate for a shortcut in the near future. The two maps can also probably be merged together into a single map.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 57 bytes

```
{('A'..it).map{" ".repeat(it-'A')+"$it ".repeat(it-'@')}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xCsJAEET7fMVyCNlFclgHEyOCVTrt1OLAi65eLiGuNiHffp5aOeW8gTf3Thz78DIOmhxwczUDQVZCzQ9Z7mRgfymhCCOm61RrFtKt6UcFSg@2t0aQJYuI5mrG8t9WKU1TaJ4eWsMeCcYEYj4qBwXgYM25Zm8jWeWgKkWHxek76aNWsEFH@tax33e/I6iOXhElU9i@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 89 bytes

```
(dotimes(m(-(char-code(read))63))(format t"~va~v@{~c ~:*~}~%"m #\  m(code-char(+ m 64))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCoAgEADQXzmK4K5wKhqa2vsFF1GjoMMwaYnu1y3f/uyxX2fO6ELa2V/IqNBuJiobnMfojSMaeyJcQ2STIFVyG7nnRyzI1MorTcVQawDGUlTJ2AHDONAv51ovHw)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
INPUT E$WHILE L$<E$L=L+1L$=CHR$(L+#X)+" "?" "*L;L$*L
WEND
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(CODE(A1)-64),REPT(" ",x-1)&REPT(CHAR(64+x),x))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnCHIQSU2mRqX8I-w?e=hXINaU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `rMj`, <s><sup>16</sup></s> 13 bytes

*Thanks to @Lyxal for -3 bytes by using Map Lambda instead of a for loop.*

```
kAḟƛ›nkAi*Ṅn꘍
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rMj&code=kA%E1%B8%9F%C6%9B%E2%80%BAnkAi*%E1%B9%84n%EA%98%8D&inputs=Z&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
               # Implicit input
kA             # Constant 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  ḟ            # Index of input in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ’
   ƛ           # Map over range [0,index)
     nkAi      # Index of n in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    ›    *     # Multiply by n+1
          Ṅ    # Join with spaces
           n꘍  # Prepend n spaces
               # 'j' flag - Join top of stack with newlines and print
```

Comment: [14 bytes using mapping and `rM`](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rM&code=kA%E1%B8%9F%C6%9B%E2%80%BAnkAi*%E1%B9%84n%EA%98%8D%2C&inputs=Z&header=&footer=) or [13 bytes using mapping and `rMj` (3 flags - might be considered _too_ "flaggy")](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rMj&code=kA%E1%B8%9F%C6%9B%E2%80%BAnkAi*%E1%B9%84n%EA%98%8D&inputs=Z&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 45 bytes

```
D:h<_
jjYZZPJ/<C-r>-
lDqqha
<esc>:,$s/\S/ & &
{$@qq@q
```

Uses lowercase. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/38UqwyaeKysrMioqwEvfxlm3yE6XK8elsDAjkcsmtTjZzkpHpVg/JlhfQU1BjataxaGw0KHw//@0/7plAA)

#### Explanation

```
D
```

Delete the input letter (we'll use it later).

```
:h<_<cr>jjYZZ
```

Yank the lowercase alphabet from an article in the help file (see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97868/16766)).

```
PJ
```

Paste the alphabet and turn the blank line (where the input used to be) into a trailing space.

```
/<C-r>-<cr>
```

Find the input letter (pasting it into the find command from the "small deletion" register `-`).

```
lD
```

Move one character to the right and delete everything till the end of the line. We now have one line containing letters `a` through the input letter, with the cursor on the last character of the line.

```
qqh
```

Begin recording macro `q`. Try going left one character. If this fails, we've gotten all the way to `a` and we're done; the macro exits. Otherwise, the cursor is now on the second-last character of the top line.

```
a<cr><esc>
```

Insert a newline after the cursor, moving the final character of the top line to its own line.

```
:,$s/\S/ & &<cr>
```

On every line from this second line till the end of the file, substitute the first non-space character for space, itself, space, and itself again. This turns a line like `c` into  `c c`,  `d d` into   `d d d`, etc.

```
{$@q
```

Go back to the first line, then go to the end of the line and run the macro recursively.

```
q@q
```

Stop recording, and call the macro.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>101</s> 99 bytes

-2 because I forgot I could remove the parentheses in `print`

```python
def f(l,a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",s=0):
 for c in a[:a.index(l)+1]:print" "*s+(c+" ")*-~s;s+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxEsIgEADA3lfcXAUhOsYSh5c4FkiCQfEggJqk8OuYbjcuZQx0qrUfLFjmW61Q38y2@@geT/@iEKeUy/vznZcV26yOXO7AhgQGHIG@SH1w1A8z81x0VxmTo4KATRbMiA282f/yOQvVVctwRV7/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```ruby
->c{i=0
(?A..c).map{" "*(i+=1)+[_1]*i*" "}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3tXXtkqszbQ24NOwd9fSSNfVyEwuqlRSUtDQytW0NNbWj4w1jtTK1gCK1tRAtqwpKS4oV3KLtvWMhAgsWQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 20 bytes

```
C65-›ɾ(nIn‹kAin*Ṅ+,)
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCJDNjUt4oC6yb4obklu4oC5a0FpbirhuYQrLCkiLCIiLCJaIl0=)

Explanation:

```
C65-›ɾ  # range from 1 to 0-25 depending on which letter is inputted
 (  # begin loop
  nI  # push n (current loop variable) spaces to the stack
   n‹kAin*Ṅ+  # which letter of the alphabet is n and push n letters 
    separated by spaces
     ,  # output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 53 bytes

```
f L{seq 0,ord(L)-65|[" "*_..`${chr(_1+65)} `*(_1+1)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P03Bp7o4tVDBQCe/KEXDR1PXzLQmWklBSSteTy9BpTo5o0gj3lDbzFSzViFBC8Q01Iyt/Z@bmJmnUM3Fmaah5K2kqVCjUFCUmVeiEa/JVfsfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

This is the "list of lines" version. Just add an "N" before the close bracket to make it look nice. (Thanks to @Erik)

```
rc'@-{)_S*\_'@+*S*}%
```

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rc'%40-%7B)_S*%5C_'%40%2B*S*N%7D%25&input=Z) (nice version).

Comment: `i64` can be `'@`

Comment: Oh, and you can re-order your code like this to avoid leading spaces: `rc'@-{_S*\)_'@+*S*N}%`

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｆ⁻℅Ｓ⁶³«×⁺℅⁺ι⁶⁴ ιＪιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBI7g0qaQoMblEw78oJTMvMUfDM6@gtCS4pCgzL11DU1NHwcxYU1OhmksBCAKAgiUavqU5JZkFOZUajikpGs5A04C6U4vAvEygchOQJiUFJSCZqakJ1udVmlsQkg@SzdTkqv3/3@2/btl/3eIcAA) Link is to verbose version.

A bit of a different approach from the other answer, let's see if it's golfable...

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 47 bytes

```
c=>[' '*i+-~i*('%c '%(i+65))for i:0..ord(c)-64]
```

Not unlike the Python answers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr7CQthiIgzKY4Ad8gjphSOpAScPs1/GuqXSpo6SR036CAceT/9gh2GzAIk9xJSqihrc5BNEHM/m43KMp145wVQivcMWCcAARjR8)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 39 bytes

```
[:(#\([' '&,1j1##)"0])i.@>:&.(65-~3&u:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1koh2kpDOUYjWl1BXU3HMMtQWVlTySBWM1PPwc5KTU/DzFS3zlit1EqTiys1OSNfIU1B3U0dzvRW//8fAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
ḢØAḣi¥p⁶ẋ"J$µLḶ⁶ẋ;"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkWHZzg@3LE489DSgkeN2x7u6lbyUjm01efhjm0QrrXS/8PtRyc93Dnj/383AA)

Function that returns a list. Append `⁸Y` to print in separate lines. Erase the footer to show actual output instead of string representation.

Answer (score 0):

## Shnap, <s>97</s> 96 bytes

*-1 byte because I remembered that the parser reads strings through newlines, so a literal newline is shorter than \n*

```
$c{n=65s=""for k:range(n,c+1){for range(n,k)s+=" "for range(n,k+1)s+=char(k)+" "s+="
"}return:s}
```

This is an anonymous function (actually, all functions in Shnap are anonymous...).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc0xCsMwDIXhvacIooNEimmHdgj4Cr2DMXYS3CpGcoYScnY3Hjp0/d4PTyd2uUZbz35j@7irBYiLdGkQx2NAvvj@RlujHyTS3kIHf3ZEh/rJCSbqj7U1J9gllFV40L1mmbm8GCPO77xIQdD2bfSjQGbmvBYkM4aCVyKqz/oF)

[Alternative version that uses the fact that blocks return the last instruction's value](https://tio.run/##Vc2xCsIwEMbx3acoh8MdkaCDDoXsvkYISRuq13BJByl99pgMDq6/7w9fntmmGkw9u0F82YTHnc3jng1AWGVYRrE8eeSLUzfaO/1goawMDPBnLWrqZiu4kGprb05wHDVJ5PJiDBjfaZWCkPu3zp8MpCOnrSDpyRe8ElF91i8)

Ungolfed/explanation:

```
$ (c) {                  //Function with 1 parameter
    n=65                    //Value of 'A'
    s=""                    //The result
    for k:range(n,c+1) {    //Inclusive range from n to c, range(n,c,1,1) also works, as third arg is step and fourth is inclusive (bool).
                            //For loop variable is k
        for range(n,k)      //Exclusive range from n to k
            s+=" "          //Add a space
        for range(n,k+1)    //Inclusive range from n to k
            s+=char(k)+" "  //Add k and a space
        s+="\n"             //Add a newline

    }
    return:s                //Return the result
}
```

I really should implement string multiplication and eval...

Answer (score 0):

### TXR Lisp, 77 bytes

```
(do mapdo(op pprinl`@{""@2}@{(take(inc @2)(gun @1))}`)(range #\A@1)(range 0))
```

Run:

```
This is the TXR Lisp interactive listener of TXR 184.
Quit with :quit or Ctrl-D on empty line. Ctrl-X ? for cheatsheet.
1> (do mapdo(op pprinl`@{""@2}@{(take(inc @2)(gun @1))}`)(range #\A@1)(range 0))
#<interpreted fun: lambda (#:arg-01-0173 . #:rest-0172)>
2> [*1 #\F]
A
 B B
  C C C
   D D D D
    E E E E E
     F F F F F F
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 26 bytes

Should meet OPs specs.

```
VhxrG1w++*dNr@GN1*+dr@GN1N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyyjosjdsFxbWyvFr8jB3c9QSzsFTPv9/x8FAA)

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood. You must have exactly one space between the characters, not many. See my answer for clarifications.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 179 bytes

Well, someone ought to post the most un-original method, I might as well be that someone.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){char n;cin>>n;for(char i='A';i<=n;i++){for(char k='A';k<i;k++){cout<<" ";}for(int j=0;j<=i-'A';j++){cout<<i<<" ";}cout<<endl;}}
```

An easier-to-read version of the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char n;
    cin>>n;
    for (char i='A';i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<n-i;k++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for (int j=0; j<n-'A'+1;j++)
        {
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoMwEEX3niLYhYoI3U8idO0pwiS1E3WUJK7Es6fElnb533t83LZuREzpRozzbqyQtIborV76Yg/Eo2C92LBptCJEAwVxFIsmrpsDX9oLBiTue4bn6uuLkKoeFZBUDNS2zfET0yUmSTBljusepSxFCWdO8rFTd3BSUZdD94/o232WZTPDeaY0vAE)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 363 bytes

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char x='A';
        int count=0;
      for(x='A';x<='Z';x++){
        for(int x1=count;x1>0;x1--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int y=count;y>=1;y--) {
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        System.out.print(x+"\n");
       count++;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure your answer is consistent with the other answers by using a title and a byte count

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Notice that you can remove a lot of the whitespace to shorten your code. Also, your code should print a space between the letters on each line. Changing `System.out.print(x);` to `System.out.print(x+" ");` will do the trick.

Comment: How do we enter any parameter? Like that limits where we stop? This is present in the question, I don't see it in this answer.