# Jimmy needs a new pair of shoes!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, parsing

Jimmy has had a busy last week with all [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187586/will-jimmy-fall-off-his-platform) [platforms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187682/how-many-jimmys-can-fit) [and](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187731/jimmy-needs-your-help) [ropes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187759/can-jimmy-hang-on-his-rope), and poor Jimmy doesn't even have legs or feet to stand on!

---

Your job is to take a string containing multiple Jimmys and give them legs and shoes!

Get input in the form of a Jimmy String

Jimmy String => `/o\  /o\   /o\`

containing only `/o\` and

give each Jimmy in the input a pair of feet that look like this:

```
 /o\
_/ \_
```

Turn the inputed floating head Jimmy string into Jimmy with feet string, like so:

```
// Input

       /o\   /o\          /o\

// Output

       /o\   /o\          /o\
      _/ \_ _/ \_        _/ \_
```

If 2 Jimmys are close together they must move over to make room,
Jimmys will always move towards the right to make room for other Jimmys.

```
// Input

/o\/o\

// Output

 /o\  /o\
_/ \__/ \_
```

Other Jimmys that are further away must not be moved unless necessary

```
// Input

/o\/o\      /o\

// Output

 /o\  /o\   /o\
_/ \__/ \_ _/ \_

// Input

/o\/o\    /o\

// Output

 /o\  /o\  /o\
_/ \__/ \__/ \_
```

Standard rules and loopholes apply,

This is code-golf, so may the shortest answer win.

Comment: Suggested test case: ``/o\<sp>/o\<sp><sp><sp><sp><sp><sp><sp><sp>/o\/o\``, my current implementation fails because it moves the last two Jimmies towards the left instead of right.. All of your test cases succeed, though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>131</s> <s>120</s> <s>115</s> <s>114</s> <s>121</s> 118 bytes

```python
o=1;W=[]
for g in map(len,input().split('/o\\')):W+=[' '*(g-o)];o=max(o-g,0)+2
for q in' /o\ ','_/ \_':print q.join(W)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU@xTsMwEJ3rrziJ4WyaptAxVcaysiBlaKoqhCNxm/pcxxHt1wcnRQRY8PD8dO/uvTt79TWbVV/yG6UOEXtOH9dZut2Jd3ZQgTZwKqxsyETa2M5LFbe20V7ikvMclUqyebpFwHtZLVjt1pyeiovkRRU9qPlqdDkHF4TQDxjhfgn5HhPrtPFwjg@sjcxUH6LFR60bghfXUSJm3l0DzuhCJQzbiUBLsh42z08b59gN6quj4ijEHRy61oPnsOuRoO0cga8JmiJU2RDoNng4R6WP41iM2TcEhNsbrpm@H0Xsx0tHKr7pJAv8Gprwb99v6d/ATw)

4 bytes thx to [movatica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86751/movatica); 10 bytes lost for bug fix.

Comment: `o+=2-len(g)` saves you a byte

Comment: [118 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY69rsIwDIVn8hTenNzydxmLMsLKgtSBIgS9AQIlDiYIePqSFkHvQGRZ1pfj4@MfYU9uVBX0ZzQjYkX6d5zpxVJsiWEH1sXy1yBV/@JLGyQOKM9RpVmiFwj4I0vj5E71SC3HlOjT@i5HvRfrDlXjco4WCHEPsIurAeQrTD1bF@DcP5B1MlNVPC1ue1samPPVpKIT@BF7x9xNAXU6EcfC@ACT2XTCTFz/btisj6JqMjW5xGeE@n1jbwgv0vavwlb@n0Er@jg@AQ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @movatica: there was a bug, but it was offset by your edits :).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
 Ｆ⌕Ａθ/«Ｊ∧ι⊖ι¹ＷＫＫ→Ｐ_/ \_Ｍ↗/o\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BC8IwDIXP268IPaUwGV71NBAPwmCI3gpjbNGVdW0t3TyIv712Uww5vJd8j6TtG9eaRoVQOak9MmB8n96MAzxK3RVK4SMDljPO4ZUmp2m0F4OF7lBmcKDW0UjaU7ScZ7CN2eTZS0WAFdGAMVWamXB3lvfeL9tyUl7a7606ByFqto5X6mr/3O@d3AixAO8QoowNa0WRhs2sPg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

Print a space to defeat Charcoal's automatic left margin.

```
Ｆ⌕Ａθ/«
```

Loop over all of the left arms.

```
Ｊ∧ι⊖ι¹
```

Jump to the desired left foot location. Note that Charcoal has no problem drawing at `(-1, 1)`, but the question does not allow that, so we have to take care to avoid drawing at negative positions.

```
ＷＫＫ→
```

Move past any existing output.

```
Ｐ_/ \_Ｍ↗/o\
```

Output the feet and then move to output the Jimmy.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <s>77</s> 75 bytes

The "don't move Jimmy if not needed" rule was quite an ordeal to work around but I think it worked out quite well. Shorter than Python by quite a bit (at time of writing), at least.

-2 bytes from recursive.

```ruby
r=/(\\ ?|^)(\S+) ?/
gsub(r){"#$1 #$2"}while~r
puts$_
gsub(/ .o. ?/,'_/ \_')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8hWXyMmRsG@Jk5TIyZYW1PBXp8rvbg0SaNIs1pJWcVQQVnFSKm2PCMzJ7WuiKugtKRYJR6iQF9BL18PqFxHPV5fISZeXfP/f/38GAhSgAIg819@QUlmfl7xf90CAA)

Comment: Could you use `\S+` in place of `\/\S*`?

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 96 bytes

```powershell
($o=$args-split'/o.'|%{' '*($w=($l+=$_.Length-1)*($l-gt0));$l-=$w+1})-join' /o\ '
$o-join'_/ \_'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFBasMwEEX3c4pBTCqpseJmHQQ5QI8QMKVVHQdhubaCC47P7qpWGrsQl2oxSH/@fyOYyrWmbo7G2oHeUWM3CHKaXuq8UU1lC89Tt@GXVceRPwpqtSC71pRtnk2Z@6PayqBalfsnKXfhoqldb3upTq4oOabugBzIxWeW4iHjQw@wFwCJAAyHYTzf1p86SSyBf7gw2Gaucc614kxiIKexIfaLPzLnrDGylLvzwRtgCYN/wRZQ90kTSOIFV9iNBirK6uwTJPNZmVdv3sI6KYut2jRn64PwELYcjRF67TBlPtgtyOYh6Icv)

Unrolled:

```powershell
$o=$args-split'/o.'|%{
    $len += $_.Length-1
    $width = $len*($len-gt0)    # len or 0, if len < 0
    ' '*$width
    $len -= $width+1
}
# $o is array of space strings now
$o-join' /o\ '
$o-join'_/ \_'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>152</s> <s>148</s> 140 bytes

```python
o=[-4]
for i,c in enumerate(input()):o+=[max(i,o[-1]+5)]*('/'==c)
for s in' /o\ ','_/ \_':print''.join('%*s'%(b-a,s)for a,b in zip(o,o[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7dCoMwDIXv@xRFkLRaJw53I/RJVES7jnVgI/6A28t31rGNwXKRhBO@kzPc5yvao1N41jIIAoeyTPKaXHCkRihqLNV26fXYzpoZOywz47zAWJZ9uzIjsEyyOj7xOmKQgpSK7@i0gUBTrCgIaFJaNVAMo7EzwOGGxjIIowlC1iWtmLgnWtH5Zw8zMNxcs6Lm3O0I2WIRoletqE8Z5Q7oq7z/u3@lCghs42f7c/wITw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <del>40</del> 37 bytes

```
\+`(^|\S.)(/\S*) ?
$1 $2
 /o. ?
_/ \_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P0Y7QSOuJiZYT1NDPyZYS1PBnkvFUEHFiEtBP18PyInXV4iJ//9fPz8GiBTAAMgAAA)

Thanks to Value Ink for golfing off 3 bytes.

Comment: Enjoy your new shoes!

Comment: Well, tried to pretend these challenges don't exists for a while. (No relation to that Jimmy.)

Comment: I believe the pattern match I used in my Ruby answer `(\\ ?|^)(/\S*) ?` is shorter than the one in your first line and should give the same results (probably; I don't know Retina at all)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>29</s> <s>28</s> <s>24</s> 25 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¢▄▌ß╙EVäN»0►,δñï◙,Θ╙BÅhΓ?
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9bdcdde1d34556844eaf30102ceba48b0a2ce9d3428f68e23f&i=%2Fo%5C%2Fo%5C%0A%2Fo%5C%2Fo%5C++++++%2Fo%5C%0A%2Fo%5C%2Fo%5C++++%2Fo%5C&a=1&m=2)

There was a bug in the 24 byte solution that caused some off-by-1 errors in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 107 bytes

```javascript
s=>` /o\\ 
_/ \\_`.replace(/.*/g,j=>s.split(/.o./).map(s=>s.slice(n,l=s.length,n=n>l?n-l+2:2),n=1).join(j))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY@xbsMwDER3fwU3ibUttUGnAHLnTvkBAYngKq4NhhJCJb/v2knRdCjKhbh3B@I4hWuQ/jzm0nL6iPPRzeK6A9jkPVR7C97vD@YcM4U@amue7NBMrhMjmcaygGQsmlPIWm6UxiXGDTkxFHkonw077uiNW6o32w0u8gXNlEbWE@JcohRwIOA66BNLomgoDVq9c76UrWcF9eLWoDx73l3Kgx614N1YlWrV2jKGol@fEatqvawV3Of2zc/6BRV@B1fxJ/gn@zDmLw)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 111 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##lU/baoQwEH33K@Yx6eri5KKrIV9StrDY2AbcWKztQ3/eziTPCy1yJnPmXMB12m/f4TjmrzTtcU2Q/CTuskp@28JMm1v8Z/wJItUo3bxuED2OSxU8nu3pbJ9Eg/IljmpcXBKhHqUvz2kLH/fbLpKIxOolpLf9XQTJNSG9ZhyTeFZgoIOLgxYUwThAWiyYq6xIZqIdeSxYR8YHAkcbLMpfGvnAdX1BsWQUkwba6QBIBTSpTRnQCL3i2bWAA@fhwiIMNC30jqnJR0UODbr7T12bw9jRn5ACjRoeFiKZ@WsUx7DA5RMTdZXHLw)

```
function J(s)
s=[' ' s];s=replace(s,{'\/','\ /'},'\  /');for k=find(s=='o')
o(k-2:k+2)='_/ \_';end
char(s,o)
```